# How can I read and process (parse) command line arguments?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

In Python, how can we find out the command line arguments that were provided for a script, and process them?

---

<sub>Related background reading: [What does "sys.argv[1]" mean? (What is sys.argv, and where does it come from?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530). For some more specific examples, see [Implementing a "[command] [action] [parameter]" style command-line interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362426) and [How do I format positional argument help using Python's optparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642648).</sub>

Comment: Use docopt (see @ralbatross's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14790373/116891). I've tried every other way and, really, docopt is the only one I will use going forward.

Comment: I don't think there's one single best way. argparse is standard and featureful. docopt is very elegant but not in the standard library. For very easy lightweight use you can [make function default values handle comand line argument defaults for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43234054/318488).

Answer (score 617, accepted):

The canonical solution in the standard library is `argparse` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)):

Here is an example:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                    help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet",
                    action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                    help="don't print status messages to stdout")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

`argparse` supports (among other things):

- Multiple options in any order.
- Short and long options.
- Default values.
- Generation of a usage help message.

Comment: Are these built in modules the best?
Or can you think of a better custom way?

Comment: Yes, these are the best. Since they're part of the standard library, you can be sure they'll be available and they're easy to use. optparse in particular is powerful and easy.

Comment: @edgerA: What does "better custom way" mean?

Comment: optparse is one of the best; getopt is old and really ought to be considered deprecated.

Comment: at this point (12/2011), argparse is now considered a better option than optparse, correct?

Comment: Python Documentation suggests the use of [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) instead of optparse.

Comment: Since `optparse` is deprecated, the asker of the question is no longer a member on stack overflow, and this is the accepted answer on a highly visible question - please consider completely rewriting your example code to use stdlib `argparse` instead.

Comment: @AymanHourieh you did not show how to get those arguments. The documentation of this module is a mess.

Comment: Has this changed over the past 14 years? And with the transition to Python 3?

Answer (score 692):

```py
import sys

print("\n".join(sys.argv))
```

[`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a list that contains all the arguments passed to the script on the command line. `sys.argv[0]` is the script name.

Basically,

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: For really simple stuff, this is the way to go, although you probably only want to use `sys.argv[1:]` (avoids the script name).

Answer (score 134):

Just going around evangelizing for [argparse](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/) which is better for [these](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/argparse-vs-optparse.html) reasons.. essentially:

*(copied from the link)*

- argparse module can handle positional
  and optional arguments, while
  optparse can handle only optional
  arguments
- argparse isn’t dogmatic about
  what your command line interface
  should look like - options like -file
  or /file are supported, as are
  required options. Optparse refuses to
  support these features, preferring
  purity over practicality
- argparse produces more
  informative usage messages, including
  command-line usage determined from
  your arguments, and help messages for
  both positional and optional
  arguments. The optparse module
  requires you to write your own usage
  string, and has no way to display
  help for positional arguments.
- argparse supports action that
  consume a variable number of
  command-line args, while optparse
  requires that the exact number of
  arguments (e.g. 1, 2, or 3) be known
  in advance
- argparse supports parsers that
  dispatch to sub-commands, while
  optparse requires setting
  `allow_interspersed_args` and doing the
  parser dispatch manually

And my personal favorite:

- argparse allows the type and
  action parameters to `add_argument()`
  to be specified with simple
  callables, while optparse requires
  hacking class attributes like
  `STORE_ACTIONS` or `CHECK_METHODS` to get
  proper argument checking

Comment: This is now part of standard Python as of 2.7 and 3.2 :)

Comment: What are "optional arguments"? You say they're in optparse. I thought that they were arguments that may or may not be provided, but you said they're in optparse while going on to say that "optparse requires that the exact number of arguments be known in advance". So either your definition of "optional argument" differs from what I thought, or your answer is inconsistent with itself.

Comment: Just a gripe: argparse documentation is also insanely, insanely complicated. You can't get a simple answer for "how do I make a command line argument take in a single value, and how do I access that value." </gripe>

Comment: @osman This gentle [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) on argparse might help...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare "optional arguments" in this context presumably means arguments specified with option-like arguments such as `-f` or `--foo`, while "exact number of arguments be known in advance" presumably means positional arguments given without any preceding option flags.

Answer (score 78):

There is also [`argparse` stdlib module](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) (an "impovement" on stdlib's `optparse` module). Example from [the introduction to argparse](https://docs.python.org/howto/argparse.html):

```
# script.py
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'integers', metavar='int', type=int, choices=range(10),
         nargs='+', help='an integer in the range 0..9')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const', const=sum,
        default=max, help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Usage:

```
$ script.py 1 2 3 4
4

$ script.py --sum 1 2 3 4
10
```

Comment: its just a copy and paste

Comment: @blitu12345 at the time of the publication of my answer there were no other answers that mention argparse in any way. The module itself was not in stdlib¶ What do you have against code examples from the documentation? Why do you think it is necessary to come up with your own examples instead of examples provided by the author of the module? And I don't like link-only answers (I'm not alone).

Comment: Peoples coming here already had an idea whats in the documentation and will be here only for further clearance about the topic.Same was my case but what i really found here is a copy and paste from the original docs.Peace!

Comment: "Peoples coming here already had an idea whats in the documentation" - i _highly_ doubt that assumtion. somehow.

Comment: I found it difficult to figure out how to actually use the results of the parsing. In this answer, this is addressed in the last line of code (so +1). But to be honest, this example is very compact and probably far beyond the capabilities of people asking about processing command line arguments.

Answer (score 74):

If you need something fast and not very flexible

**main.py:**

```
import sys

first_name = sys.argv[1]
last_name = sys.argv[2]
print("Hello " + first_name + " " + last_name)
```

Then run `python main.py James Smith`

to produce the following output:

> Hello James Smith

Comment: A more realistic usage would be `python main.py "James Smith"` which puts `James Smith` in `sys.argv[1]` and produces an `IndexError` when you try to use the nonexistent `sys.argv[2]`.  Quoting behavior will somewhat depend on which platform and shell you run Python from.

Comment: I don't agree that my usage is less realistic. Pretend your program needs to know the exact first and last name of a person to run the script in a business where people can have multiple first and last names? If James Smith has Joseph as an extra first or last name, how would distinguish between whether Joseph is an extra first or last name if you only do `python main.py "James Joseph Smith"`? If you are concerned with index out of bounds, you can add a check for the number of provided arguments. Less realistic or not, my example shows how to handle multiple arguments.

Comment: All the other answers are for plotting a lunar landing mission. I'm just simply using `gmail-trash-msg.py MessageID`. This answer is straight forward to test `MessageID` parameter has been passed in `sys.argv[1]`.

Answer (score 53):

One way to do it is using `sys.argv`. This will print the script name as the first argument and all the other parameters that you pass to it.

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

Answer (score 53):

The [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) library is really slick.  It builds an argument dict from the usage string for your app.

Eg from the docopt readme:

```
"""Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship new <name>...
  naval_fate.py ship <name> move <x> <y> [--speed=<kn>]
  naval_fate.py ship shoot <x> <y>
  naval_fate.py mine (set|remove) <x> <y> [--moored | --drifting]
  naval_fate.py (-h | --help)
  naval_fate.py --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
  --speed=<kn>  Speed in knots [default: 10].
  --moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
  --drifting    Drifting mine.

"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='Naval Fate 2.0')
    print(arguments)
```

Comment: This has rapidly become my favorite way to go.  It's string parsing so it's kind of brittle, but it's brittle _all in one place_ and you can preview your logic at http://try.docopt.org .  Optional and mutually-exclusive arguments are done in a really elegant way.

Answer (score 27):

```
#set default args as -h , if no args:
if len(sys.argv) == 1: sys.argv[1:] = ["-h"]
```

Answer (score 20):

I use optparse myself, but really like the direction Simon Willison is taking with his recently introduced [optfunc](http://github.com/simonw/optfunc/tree/master) library.  It works by:

> "introspecting a function
>   definition (including its arguments
>   and their default values) and using
>   that to construct a command line
>   argument parser."

So, for example, this function definition:

```
def geocode(s, api_key='', geocoder='google', list_geocoders=False):
```

is turned into this optparse help text:

```
    Options:
      -h, --help            show this help message and exit
      -l, --list-geocoders
      -a API_KEY, --api-key=API_KEY
      -g GEOCODER, --geocoder=GEOCODER
```

Answer (score 9):

I like getopt from stdlib, eg:

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'h', ['help'])
except getopt.GetoptError, err: 
    usage(err)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'): 
        usage()

if len(args) != 1:
    usage("specify thing...")
```

Lately I have been wrapping something similiar to this to make things less verbose (eg; making "-h" implicit).

Answer (score 9):

Pocoo's [click](http://click.pocoo.org/) is more intuitive, requires less boilerplate, and is at least as powerful as argparse.

The only weakness I've encountered so far is that you can't do much customization to help pages, but that usually isn't a requirement and [docopt](http://docopt.org/) seems like the clear choice when it is.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) "The optparse module is deprecated with and will not be developed further; development will continue with the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module."

Answer (score 6):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))

Assuming the Python code above is saved into a file called prog.py
$ python prog.py -h

Ref-link: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in a little Python module I wrote to make handling of command line arguments even easier (open source and free to use) - [Commando](http://freshmeat.net/projects/commando)

Comment: There is already another command-line parsing module named Commando: https://github.com/lakshmivyas/commando. It wraps argparse by using decorators.

Comment: python and wheel re-invention

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option is [argh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh). It builds on argparse, and lets you write things like:

```
import argh

# declaring:

def echo(text):
    "Returns given word as is."
    return text

def greet(name, greeting='Hello'):
    "Greets the user with given name. The greeting is customizable."
    return greeting + ', ' + name

# assembling:

parser = argh.ArghParser()
parser.add_commands([echo, greet])

# dispatching:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser.dispatch()
```

It will automatically generate help and so on, and you can use decorators to provide extra guidance on how the arg-parsing should work.

Comment: This is the best solution. Using `argh` is easier than another libs or using `sys`.

Comment: I wanted to like `argh` but it's not particularly suitable for scenarios where your utmost desire is not to have a command with subcommands.

Comment: @tripleee YMMV, but I found that this was more of a defect in the documentation than in the library itself. It seems perfectly feasible to have `def frobnicate_spleches(...)` defining a function that does whatever your script does, then doing `if __name__ == '__main__': argh.dispatch_command(frobnicate_spleches)` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend looking at [docopt](http://docopt.org/) as a simple alternative to these others.

docopt is a new project that works by parsing your --help usage message rather than requiring you to implement everything yourself. You just have to put your usage message in the POSIX format.

Answer (score 3):

Also with python3 you might find convenient to use Extended Iterable Unpacking to handle optional positional arguments without additional dependencies:

```
try:
   _, arg1, arg2, arg3, *_ = sys.argv + [None] * 2
except ValueError:
   print("Not enough arguments", file=sys.stderr) # unhandled exception traceback is meaningful enough also
   exit(-1)
```

The above `argv` unpack makes `arg2` and `arg3` "optional" - if they are not specified in `argv`, they will be None, while if the first is not specified, ValueError will be thouwn:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    _, arg1, arg2, arg3, *_ = sys.argv + [None] * 2
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 4, got 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Reason for the new answer:

1. Existing answers specify multiple options.
2. Standard option is to use `argparse`, a few answers provided examples from the documentation, and one answer suggested the advantage of it. But all fail to explain the answer adequately/clearly to the actual question by OP, at least for newbies.

An example of `argparse`:

```
import argparse


def load_config(conf_file):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    //Specifies one argument from the command line
    //You can have any number of arguments like this
    parser.add_argument("conf_file", help="configuration file for the application") 
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = load_config(args.conf_file)
```

Above program expects a config file as an argument. If you provide it, it will execute happily. If not, it will print the following

```
usage: test.py [-h] conf_file
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: conf_file
```

- You can have the option to specify if the argument is optional.
- You can specify the expected type for the argument using `type` key

  `parser.add_argument("age", type=int, help="age of the person")`
- You can specify default value for the arguments by specifying `default` key

This [document](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) will help you to understand it to an extent.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

# Command line arguments are stored into sys.argv
# print(sys.argv[1:])

# I used the slice [1:] to print all the elements except the first
# This because the first element of sys.argv is the program name
# So the first argument is sys.argv[1], the second is sys.argv[2] ecc

print("File name: " + sys.argv[0])
print("Arguments:")
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(i)
```

Let's name this file `command_line.py` and let's run it:

```
C:\Users\simone> python command_line.py arg1 arg2 arg3 ecc
File name: command_line.py
Arguments:
arg1
arg2
arg3
ecc
```

Now let's write a simple program, `sum.py`:

```
import sys

try:
    print(sum(map(float, sys.argv[1:])))
except:
    print("An error has occurred")
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\simone> python sum.py 10 4 6 3
23
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is [entrypoint2](https://github.com/ponty/entrypoint2). Example:

```
from entrypoint2 import entrypoint
@entrypoint
def add(file, quiet=True): 
    ''' This function writes report.

    :param file: write report to FILE
    :param quiet: don't print status messages to stdout
    '''
    print file,quiet
```

help text:

```
usage: report.py [-h] [-q] [--debug] file

This function writes report.

positional arguments:
  file         write report to FILE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -q, --quiet  don't print status messages to stdout
  --debug      set logging level to DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

Several of our biotechnology clients have posed these two questions recently:

- How can we execute a Python script as a command?
- How can we pass input values to a Python script when it is executed as a command?

I have included a Python script below which I believe answers both questions. Let's assume the following Python script is saved in the file test.py:

```
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# file name: test.py
#
# input values: data  - location of data to be processed
#               date  - date data were delivered for processing
#               study - name of the study where data originated
#               logs  - location where log files should be written 
#
# macOS usage: 
#
#   python3 test.py "/Users/lawrence/data" "20220518" "XYZ123" "/Users/lawrence/logs"
#
# Windows usage: 
#
#   python test.py "D:\data" "20220518" "XYZ123" "D:\logs"
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# import needed modules...
#
import sys
import datetime

def main(argv):

   #
   # print message that process is starting...
   #
   print("test process starting at", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M"))

   #
   # set local values from input values...
   #
   data = sys.argv[1]
   date = sys.argv[2]
   study = sys.argv[3]
   logs = sys.argv[4]

   #
   # print input arguments...
   #
   print("data value is", data)
   print("date value is", date)
   print("study value is", study)
   print("logs value is", logs)

   #
   # print message that process is ending...
   #
   print("test process ending at", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M"))

#
# call main() to begin processing...
#

if __name__ == '__main__':

   main(sys.argv)
```

The script can be executed on a macOS computer in a Terminal shell as shown below and the results will be printed to standard output (be sure the current directory includes the test.py file):

```
$ python3 test.py "/Users/lawrence/data" "20220518" "XYZ123" "/Users/lawrence/logs"
test process starting at 20220518 16:51
data value is /Users/lawrence/data
date value is 20220518
study value is XYZ123
logs value is /Users/lawrence/logs
test process ending at 20220518 16:51
```

The script can also be executed on a Windows computer in a Command Prompt as shown below and the results will be printed to standard output (be sure the current directory includes the test.py file):

```
D:\scripts>python test.py "D:\data" "20220518" "XYZ123" "D:\logs"
test process starting at 20220518 17:20
data value is D:\data
date value is 20220518
study value is XYZ123
logs value is D:\logs
test process ending at 20220518 17:20
```

This script answers both questions posed above and is a good starting point for developing scripts that will be executed as commands with input values.

Answer (score 0):

This handles simple switches, value switches with optional alternative flags.

```
import sys

# [IN] argv - array of args
# [IN] switch - switch to seek
# [IN] val - expecting value
# [IN] alt - switch alternative
# returns value or True if val not expected
def parse_cmd(argv,switch,val=None,alt=None):
    for idx, x in enumerate(argv):
        if x == switch or x == alt:
            if val:
                if len(argv) > (idx+1):            
                    if not argv[idx+1].startswith('-'):
                        return argv[idx+1]
            else:
                return True

//expecting a value for -i
i = parse_cmd(sys.argv[1:],"-i", True, "--input")

//no value needed for -p
p = parse_cmd(sys.argv[1:],"-p")
```