# Proper help for arguments

Tags: python, optparse

Python optparse works very good when script usage is something like this

```
%prog [options] [args]
```

But I need to write help for script with 1 required argument, so usage will be like this

```
%prog action [options] [args]
```

You can see something similar when you use Subversion - its usage string is

```
svn <subcommand> [options] [args]
```

So my question is: is it possible to prepare help for required argument with optparse in the manner of Subversion? As a result I want to see help like this:

```
Usage: python myscript.py action [options] [args]

Available actions:
  foo
  bar

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Verbose mode. Output debug log to stdout.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a good solution for you is [argparse](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/), which has been [proposed for inclusion in Python 2.7 and 3.2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/).  It handles subcommands, I believe as you want, and the linked page includes a link to a page on porting your code from optparse.

See also the question [command-line-arguments-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python), into which someone edited a list of references that appears to include exactly the same thing you want:

Comment: Yes, looks like argparse is what I need.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can set the usage string like this:

```
usage = "%prog action [options] [args]"
parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
parser.add_option("-v", "--verbose",
                  action="store_true", dest="verbose", default=True,
                  help="make lots of noise [default]")
```

Prints the following:

```
Usage:  action [options] [args]

Options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  make lots of noise [default]
```

This was copied almost verbatim from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#generating-help).

**Edit:**

Based on your comment you could use the description to achieve something similar, though you can't put new-line characters in it.

```
parser.description = 'Available actions: foo, bar'
```

Will look like this:

```
Usage:  action [options] [args]

Available actions: foo, bar

Options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  make lots of noise [default]
```

Comment: I know that I can set any usage string. My question is about preparing help for arguments. For options I can use something like

parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', dest='VERBOSE', default=False, help='Verbose mode. Output debug log to stdout.')

And I'll get pretty formatted help for -v option. But I want to add information about argument usage as well. For now I can see the only way is to use option instead of argument, so I will have to write python myscript.py -a foo [...] instead of python myscript.py foo [...]

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem as well. My solution was to declare commands in a list or tuple, format them into the `usage` parameter of OptionParser and then use the args list provided by the parser to determine if a command was provided or not, since it technically has to be `args[0]`. Eg:

```
self.commands = ('foo', 'bar' ...)
self.parser = <initialized instance of OptionParser>
(self.options, self.args) = parser.parse_args()

if len(self.args) == 0:
   self.parser.error("Command required")

self.command = self.args[0]
if not self.command in self.commands:
   self.parser.error("Command not recognized")

#... etc
```

This kinda gets you a command system that looks like Subversion's, but admittedly optparse could be better. I've heard the **argparse** module is supposed to make it into the stdlib, but with 2.7 being the last of the 2 series releases, I guess you'd have to wait for it to be incorporated into 3.x. Of course you can just install argparse, but that's a drag in some cases.

Comment: Reading and validating arguments is not a problem - I already implemented this with dictionary instead of tuple (key is action and value is action description). The problem is help preparation.