# How do I access command line arguments?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I use python to create my project settings setup, but I need help getting the command line arguments.

I tried this on the terminal:

```
$python myfile.py var1 var2 var3
```

In my Python file, I want to use all variables that are input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 871, accepted):

[Python tutorial explains it](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/stdlib.html#command-line-arguments):

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

More specifically, if you run `python example.py one two three`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.argv)
['example.py', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 270):

I highly recommend [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) which comes with Python 2.7 and later.

The `argparse` module reduces boiler plate code and makes your code more robust, because the module handles all standard use cases (including subcommands), generates the help and usage for you, checks and sanitize the user input - all stuff you have to worry about when you are using `sys.argv` approach. And it is for free (built-in).

Here a small example:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("simple_example")
parser.add_argument("counter", help="An integer will be increased by 1 and printed.", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.counter + 1)
```

and the output for `python prog.py -h`

```sh
usage: simple_example [-h] counter
    
positional arguments:
  counter     counter will be increased by 1 and printed.
    
optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and the output for `python prog.py 1` As one would expect:

```
2
```

Comment: Quality answer, not really sure why anyone here would use any of the other approaches given here. *Especially* since it's built in! Don't you guys have better things to do than parsing?

Comment: Just to mention how you should access the specific argument in args namespace: args.counter

Comment: @Bassinator In cases when no parsing of arguments is needed.

Comment: to use default value, without specific value in the command line, you can use something like:
`parser.add_argument('var3', nargs='?', type=int, default=3)`
var3 is a optional param, if you don't specify a value in the command line you can access to var3 in your code, default value for var3=3

Comment: Can type be `int` or `float`?

Comment: Yes, snd many more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

Comment: @Bassinator sometimes you want to record the exact command used. For example in machine learning experiments, logging sys.argv is an easy way to log the command line without having to update the code after any improvements to the argument definitions for argparse.ArgumentParser

Comment: @Bassinator `sys.argv[1]` is also quicker and less troublesome if you're just writing a quick-and-dirty script to process some data of yours, and don't need to be fancy.

Answer (score 243):

#### To get *only* the command line arguments

(not including the name of the Python file)

```
import sys

sys.argv[1:]
```

The `[1:]` is a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/208273) starting from the second element (index 1) and going to the end of the arguments list.  This is because the first element is the name of the Python file, and we want to remove that.

Comment: Do we really need to import all of sys?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm open to input because I don't write a lot of Python code these days, but [my employer's Python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#22-imports) does indeed recommend using imports in this manner.

Comment: Ok, so, I checked, and - it turns out there is little cost to "importing sys". It's mostly about the set of identifiers to search rather than the loading of libraries.

Answer (score 97):

Python code:

```
import sys

# main
param_1= sys.argv[1] 
param_2= sys.argv[2] 
param_3= sys.argv[3]  
print 'Params=', param_1, param_2, param_3
```

Invocation:

```
$python myfile.py var1 var2 var3
```

Output:

```
Params= var1 var2 var3
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use `sys.argv` to get the arguments as a list.

If you need to access individual elements, you can use

```
sys.argv[i]
```

where `i` is index, `0` will give you the python filename being executed. Any index after that are the arguments passed.

Answer (score 22):

You can access arguments by key using "argparse".

Let's say that we have this command:

```
python main.py --product_id 1001028
```

To access the argument product_id, we need to declare it first and then get it:

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--product_id', dest='product_id', type=str, help='Add product_id')
args = parser.parse_args()

print (args.product_id)
```

Output:

```
1001028
```

Answer (score 8):

If you call it like this: `$ python myfile.py var1 var2 var3`

```
import sys

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]
```

Similar to arrays you also have `sys.argv[0]` which is always the current working directory.

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is not the current working directory. It is the name of the file that is executing.

Answer (score 6):

Some additional things that I can think of.

As @allsyed said sys.argv gives a list of components (including program name), so if you want to know the number of elements passed through command line you can use len() to determine it. Based on this, you can design exception/error messages if user didn't pass specific number of parameters.

Also if you looking for a better way to handle command line arguments, I would suggest you look at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 6):

First, You will need to import **sys**

> sys - System-specific parameters and functions

This module provides access to certain variables used and maintained by the interpreter, and to functions that interact strongly with the interpreter. This module is still available. I will edit this post in case this module is not working anymore.

And then, you can print the numbers of arguments or what you want here, the list of arguments.

Follow the script below :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments entered :' len(sys.argv)

print 'Your argument list :' str(sys.argv)
```

Then, run your python script :

```
$ python arguments_List.py chocolate milk hot_Chocolate
```

And you will have the result that you were asking :

```
Number of arguments entered : 4
Your argument list : ['arguments_List.py', 'chocolate', 'milk', 'hot_Chocolate']
```

Hope that helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

should use of sys ( system ) module .
the arguments has str type and are in an array

**NOTICE** : argv is not function or class and is variable & can change

**NOTICE** : argv[0] is file name

*NOTICE* : because python written in c , C have main(int argc , char *argv[]); but argc in sys module does not exits

*NOTICE* : sys module is named System and written in C that NOT A SOURCE BASED MODULE

```py
from sys import argv # or
from sys import * # or
import sys 

# code
print("is list") if type(sys.argv) == list else pass #  is list ,or
print("is list") if type(argv) == list else pass # is list
# arguments are str ( string )
print(type(sys.argv[1])) # str
# command : python filename.py 1 2 3
print(len(sys.argv)) # 3
print(sys.argv[1],'\n',sys.argv[2]'\n',sys.argv[3]) # following
'''
1
2
3
'''
# command : python filename.py 123
print(len(sys.argv)) # 1
print(sys.argv[1]) # following
'''
123
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code, you can check whether the arguments are entered. If it is the case, the arguments are printed; otherwise, a message stating that the arguments are not entered is printed.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
   print("No arguments were given")
else:
   for arg in sys.argv:
      print(arg)
```

Comment: This is wrong
`AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'args'``

Comment: @BrenoLeitão it is actually sys.argv