# CLI in such format - file.py --word 'Hello world!'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have such function:

```
def say(word):
    print(word)
```

And I want to run it through CMD in such way:

```
file.py --word 'Hello world!'
```

I know it works somehow that way, but I can't find out how it is.

Comment: You mean you want to take command line arguments in Python (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033723/3001761)? Or you don't know how to call the function? Or something else?

Comment: take look at this --> https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv

Comment: I guess that might be it. It's a task for my studies where I should control a variable inside a program through CMD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the argparse module

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('word', type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.word)  # say(args.word)
```