# how to input only part of filename in the command line in python

Tags: python

`head = csv.reader(open("header.csv"))`

I have something like this. here is it possible to provide part of the input in the command line like this.

```
head = csv.reader(open("sys.argv[1]".csv"))
```

So that I can launch the script as

```
python test.py header
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access command line arguments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033723/how-do-i-access-command-line-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format)

```
head = csv.reader(open('{}.csv'.format(sys.argv[1])))
```

or in python 3.6 or later

```
head = csv.reader(open(f'{sys.argv[1]}.csv'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since python 3.6 you can use f-strings.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

```
head = csv.reader(open(f'{sys.argv[1]}.csv'))
```