# Command line input in python using os and system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the iris_dataset using os.system from python, then while taking the values I am copying the value from iris_dataset to Temp and then I am opening the Temp file and using it like below.

```
import os

import sys

os.system("/home/mine/Desktop/C4.5/c4.5 -u -f iris_dataset")

os.system("/home/mine/Desktop/C4.5/c4.5rules -u -f iris_dataset > Temp")

f=open('Temp')
```

Once I am done with my program I am executing my program like : `python3 prog_name.py` In this case whenever I am using any other dataset apart from iris_dataset, I need to open the program again and change that name in the above code where iris_dataset is written.

Instead of this I just want to make a change i.e while executing the program I want to write : `python3 prog_name.py my_data_set_name` in kind of command line, so that it becomes more easy to change the datasets as per my wish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033723/how-do-i-access-command-line-arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033723/how-do-i-access-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sys.argv`

```
import os

import sys

dataset = sys.argv[1]

os.system(f"/home/mine/Desktop/C4.5/c4.5 -u -f {dataset}")

os.system(f"/home/mine/Desktop/C4.5/c4.5rules -u -f {dataset} > Temp")

f=open('Temp')
```

Please note that I used python's f-strings for better code readability. Feel free to use the `dataset` variable in any way you see fit

[sys.argv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

Comment: Yeah! Got it. Thank you. It is working fine.

Comment: Your answer (even if correct) was alredy answered in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033723/how-do-i-access-command-line-arguments?noredirect=1&lq=1). You should check similar questions (usually also present on the right panel) before replying

Comment: Okay, I'll do that from next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/) to create a nice console line interface. It can give you nice help text, options etc.

For example:

```py
import os
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("dataset")
def init(dataset):
    """
    DATASET - Dataset to process
    """
    process_dataset(dataset)


def process_dataset(dataset):
    os.system(f"/home/mine/Desktop/C4.5/c4.5 -u -f {dataset}")
    os.system(f"/home/mine/Desktop/C4.5/c4.5rules -u -f {dataset} > Temp")
    f=open('Temp')
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```