# One python script loops over a variable and runs 3 other scripts that use the said variable

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to loop over a range of a variable and run 3 python scripts each of which uses the said variable. Currently I can run the 3 scripts without being able to loop thru the range of variable that the called scripts need. i currently have the following code:

```
import subprocess

cmd='python foo.py'
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
out,err=p.communicate()

cmd='python bar.py'
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
out,err=p.communicate()

cmd='python bas.py'
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
out,err=p.communicate()
```

but what i need is something like the below:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    cmd='python foo.py'
    p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
    out,err=p.communicate()

    cmd='python bar.py'
    p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
    out,err=p.communicate()

    cmd='python bas.py'
    p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
    out,err=p.communicate()
```

how can i pass x into foo, bar and bas and loop over the range of x?
thank you for your help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033723/how-do-i-access-command-line-arguments

Comment: Are there reasons you can't just `import` them?

Comment: Hi Axe319, i'm not sure how to loop thru x with the import

Comment: hi sashoalm - i'm not sure the question you linked to answers my specific problem. could also be that my rather basic knowledge of python is preventing me from understanding it...

Comment: If you say passing x into foo, do you mean that foo should get the value of x? If so, why not pass it as a command-line parameter if it a simple variable? And if it is more complex, create a temporary pickle-file and pass the path to the file to foo. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm