# Need help passing two string arguments

Tags: python

Novice here. I'm extremely new to python programming and I don't have any coding experience. I'm doing this for one of my college requirements. As the title shows, I need help passing two string arguments to my python code. This is what I have so far:

```
import sys 
print("--------------------")
print("Initials:   OC")
print("Nickname:   Waldo ")
print("--------------------")
print("Initials:", sys.argv[2])
python3 
main.py arg1 arg2
```

This is what it's asking me to do: [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UMAt.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033723/how-do-i-access-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys` module:

myfile.py

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

This prints you all the inputs with also the name of the program as the first item.

For example if you run `python myfile.py a1 a2 a3` it will print `['ttt.py', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3']`.

So if you want two inputs you have to run this:

myfile.py

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)

print("--------------------")
print(f"Initials:   {sys.argv[1]}")
print(f"Nickname:   {sys.argv[2]} ")
print("--------------------")
```

So if you run `python myfile.py a1 a2` it will print this:

```
--------------------
Initials:   a1
Nickname:   a2
--------------------
```

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: I need to use this specific command: python3 main.py arg1 arg2. How can I incorporate this into my python?

Comment: @OsvaldoCarrillo This is exactly what I explained above. If you put the code I said in my answer in `main.py` file and then type `python3 main.py arg1 arg2` then the output would be `arg1` for *Initials* and `arg2` for *Nickname*. Like you wanted.