# Python Script does not take sys.argv in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command-line-arguments

I have two computers with Windows, and I just found that on one of them, if I ran python code directly, like:

```
test_args.py input1 input2
```

Python will not recognized the input I gave, but this works:

```
python test_args.py input1 input2
```

I tried the code:

```
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

And the first way(test_args.py input1 input2) returns:

```
Number of arguments: 1 arguments.
Argument List: ['D:\\Test\\args\\test_args.py']
```

While the sceond way (python test_args.py input1 input2) returns:

```
Number of arguments: 3 arguments.
Argument List: ['D:\\Test\\args\\test_args.py', 'input1', 'input2']
```

Any idea on what this could happen?
This issue only happens in one of my computers, both have same version of Windows.

Thanks!

### SOLVED:

I search in regedit keyword "python" and found two keys missing %* after "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1":

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command

And .py is associated with py_auto_file even though I tried assoc .py Python.File

Changing the two keys fixed this issue, thanks!

Comment: maybe you have different versions of python installed in both. Try running `python -V` to confirm the version numbers.

Comment: Somehow you lost the proper file association. The default for Python 2.7 is `assoc .py=Python.File` and `ftype Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: assoc .py=Python.File did not change the association of .py for some reason. Just found out that the value of .py under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py is py_auto_file for some reason. Changing the value in py_auto_file solve this issue, thanks!

Comment: `HKCR` is a merged view of `HKLM\Software\Classes` (local machine) and `HKCU\Software\Classes` (user). The user settings in the `HKCU` hive takes precedence in the merged view. But the cmd shell's `assoc` and `ftype` commands only edit the `HKLM` settings.

Comment: Yes, `py_auto_file` and `pyw_auto_file` are the culprits. I just did an anaconda install on a brand new Windows 8 machine. Setting all the `assoc` and `ftype` values didn't work, but after fixing these two values everything is good.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It saved a lot of my time. In my case the registry configuration was slightly different.

On the PC1 (where it worked) there was neither HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe nor HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file, however there was HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command with a standard property with the value "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*.

On the PC2 (there it didnt work) there was HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command with the wrong value and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command file the wrong value as well.

Comment: I have corrected only the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command on the PC2 and it started working (no console reopen was required). I also removed the second parameter HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file and convinced that it just had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Check what is the association of *.py files on these two computers. The script may be executed by different Python interpreters.

Comment: Both of my computers use Anaconda. I've made sure that the associations are the same. But it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @ZeweiSong, there are way many locations where file type associations can be set. Check `HKLM\Software\Classes`, `HKLM\Software\Classes\Applications`, and `HKLM\Software\RegisteredApplications`, and the same subkeys under the per-user `HKCU` hive. Also check `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`. Refer to [File Types and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @eryksun I found two keys missing the %*, guess that is for the sys input

Comment: @ZeweiSong, `"%1"` is the script path, and `%*` is the rest of the arguments.