# How to get the count of command line parameters in python regardless of python keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters

I have a small sample program in python:

```
import sys
print ("This is the name of the script: "+ sys.argv[0])
print ("Number of arguments: " + str(len(sys.argv)))
print ("The arguments are: " + str(sys.argv))
```

I run it in Windows CLI:

```
python args.py -a -b
```

Output:

```
This is the name of the script: args.py
Number of arguments: 3
The arguments are: ['args.py', '-a', '-b']
```

Looks good. Now I call it without specifying "python":

```
args.py -a -b
```

Now the output is totally different:

```
This is the name of the script: C:\args.py
Number of arguments: 1
The arguments are: ['C:\\args.py']
```

Shouldnt I be getting the same result? Why does it show a different argument count, even though python.exe is executing the program in both cases? How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a solution [on this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29540541/1090302), reproduced below:

> I search in regedit keyword "python" and found two keys missing `%*` after `"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1":`
>
> `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe`
>
> `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command`
>
> And `.py` is associated with `py_auto_file` even though I tried `assoc .py Python.File`
>
> Changing the two keys fixed this issue, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Don't use sys.arg for any significant argument parsing. Use [argparse.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)