# Python - ValueError: too many values to unpack - why?

Tags: python, argv

I'm very new to Python. I need to compare two lists of words and detect those words in one list which are not in the other.
Here are two test files

big_list.txt

```
[coin, co-operate, accurate, achieve, adapt, adjust, admire, admission, enter, advance, adventure, aeroplane, plane, affair, aim, objective, annual, approach, approve, argument]
```

small_list.txt

```
[coin, co-operate,  football, accurate, achieve, adapt, amazing, adjust, admire, admission, enter, advance, breakfast]
```

with this expected output

```
[football, amazing, breakfast]
```

I have a pretty simple Python script here

```
from sys import argv
big_list, small_list = argv
blist = open(big_list).read()
slist = open(small_list).read()
dlist = [item for item in slist if item not in blist]
diff_list = open(dlist, 'w').write()
diff_list.close()
```

but when run it returns this error message

```
roy@medea:~/e2tw/list_comparison$ python file_comp1.py big_list.txt small_list.txt
  Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "file_comp1.py", line 3, in <module>
          big_list, small_list = argv
   ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Side-note: WTH is going on with those last lines? You're opening a `list`, `write`-ing nothing to it, storing the return from `write` (hint: Not a file object), then `close`-ing the non-file. Also, `read`ing files with Python `list` literals in them doesn't create `list`s. You'll need `ast.literal_eval` to convert strings in Python literal form to actual Python objects instead of raw bytes.

Comment: As you are very new to python, I think we should not downvote your question. Look at my answer suggested, I think this code should have enough boilerplate to help you write solid code and further experiment with your tasks. If there are errors please comment, I will correct. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your observations are very valid. Of note is that OP's file content cannot be evaluated directly with `ast` because the items in the list are not string literals.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Depends on whether the question's described format is accurate. The desired end result isn't representable in Python either (aside from terrible manual formatting), so it's possible it's "pseudodata".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try at least(**Please look at the second code snippet for a real fully working answer**):

```
from sys import argv
big_list, small_list = argv[-2:]
blist = open(big_list).read()
slist = open(small_list).read()
dlist = [item for item in slist if item not in blist]
diff_list = open(dlist, 'w').write()
diff_list.close()
```

The first entry will always be your script itself, but there are many things not working as others partially pointed already out. Look below working code :-) to get you going.

You can also use `[1:]` which is more widely used to ignore the first entry at index 0 and take all the rest. In hackish/rookie code I prefer the explicit -"number of expected" parameters though.

But maybe better write **something like this** to get going:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


def read_list_from_file(a_path):
    """Simple parser transforming a [a, b,] text in file
    at a_path into a list."""
    return [z.strip() for z in open(a_path, 'rt').read().strip('[]').split(',')]


def a_not_in_b_list(a_seq, b_seq):
    """Return the list of entries in a_seq but not in b_seq."""
    return [item for item in a_seq if item not in b_seq]


def main():
    """Drive the diff."""
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        big_list, small_list = sys.argv[1:]
    else:
        print("Usage:", __file__, "<big-list-file> <small-list-file>")
        return 2
    # Do something with the file names given here
    b_list = read_list_from_file(big_list)
    s_list = read_list_from_file(small_list)

    with open('diff_list.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('%s\n' % (repr(a_not_in_b_list(s_list, b_list)),))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Running this on your text files gives in `diff_list.txt`:

```
['football', 'amazing', 'breakfast']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
big_list, small_list = argv[1:]
```

Why? Because **three** parameters will be passed to your script by default, with `argv[0]` being the script name

P.S. In your last two lines, there is a bug waiting to go off. You *can't* pass a list as a reference to a file object. You should do this instead:

```
output_file = open("filename.txt", "w")
output_file.write("[%s]" % ", ".join(dlist))
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Exactly: sys.argv contains name of your script as well – https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: @starfury Thanks for the link

Comment: dlist is giving the output ['z','k'] in his code why?

Answer (score 1):

`argv[0]` contains the name of the python script being run (analogous to the way C's `argv[0]` has the executable name). You obviously cannot assgin three values (`['file_comp1.py', 'big_list.txt', 'small_list.txt']`) into two variables. You could, e.g., slice `argv` to get only the second argument and onwards:

```
big_list, small_list = argv[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv
big_list = argv[1]
small_list = argv[2]
blist = open(big_list).read()
slist = open(small_list).read()
dlist = [item for item in slist if item not in blist]
diff_list = open(dlist, 'w').write()
diff_list.close()
```

Check out this answer on how to use argv.[Using argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script)

`argv[0]` is the script name.

Comment: @Dilettante Thanks for your very helpful answer. Your suggested script is instructive. I like the function definitions, being a complete Python newbie I was unaware of this capability in Python, tho, of course, it's common enough in other languages. Just one other point, I wonder how your script would scale as some of the comparisons I intend to make involve lists containing around 10,000 words.  To all the others, thanks too. SO is a really awesome community.