# Passing command line arguments in python by pytest

Tags: python

I am able to pass command line arguments when running

```
python <filename>.py arg1
```

But when am trying to pass the command line arguments for running pytest it fails and gives error as below. Can you please advise.

```
pytest <filename>.py arg1
ERROR: file not found: arg1
```

EDIT:

For example am thinking of using it this way assuming I have passed an argument and am reading it via sys.argv:

```
import sys
arg = sys.argv[3]
def f():
    return 3

def test_function():
    assert f() == arg
```

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to pass the data and store it to a variable in the script. Is it possible..? thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't parameterize your tests like this. Test should be as self contained as possible. If you have to test `argv`s for you application, mock them.

Comment: Thanks agreed. I just wanted to try if its possible to pass arguments that way. Please let me know if at all its possible any way.

Comment: Helpful solution found here based on the pytest doc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813725/9257803

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `pytest <filename>.py arg1` command is trying to call pytest on two modules `<filename>.py` and `arg1` , But there is no module arg1.

If you want to pass some argument before running pytest then run the pytest from a python script after extracting your variable.

As others suggested though you would probably want to parameterize your tests in some other way, Try:[Parameterized pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html).

```
# run.py
import pytest
import sys

def main():
    # extract your arg here
    print('Extracted arg is ==> %s' % sys.argv[2])
    pytest.main([sys.argv[1]])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

call this using `python run.py filename.py arg1`

Comment: Unfortunately am getting the same error as I was getting before - Error: File not found

Comment: Can you tell me what you meant by **extract your arg here

Comment: @anukb I've updated the code, But I'm not sure how many args you will pass. You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script for more details about sys arg

Answer (score 5):

Here's the method I just cooked up from reading the [parameterized pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html?highlight=pytest_generate_tests#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) and hacking for a while... I don't know how stable or good it is going to be overall since I just got it working.
I did however check that HTML coverage generation works with this method.

- add a file to your test directory for [configuring the command-line args you want to pass](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=addoption#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption):

  - `tests\conftest.py`

```
# this is just so we can pass --server and --port from the pytest command-line
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    ''' attaches optional cmd-line args to the pytest machinery '''
    parser.addoption("--server", action="append", default=[], help="real server hostname/IP")
    parser.addoption("--port", action="append", default=[], help="real server port number")
```

- and then add a test file, with this special `pytest_generate_tests` function [which is called when collecting a test function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html?highlight=pytest_generate_tests#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)

  - `tests\test_junk.py`

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    ''' just to attach the cmd-line args to a test-class that needs them '''
    server_from_cmd_line = metafunc.config.getoption("server")
    port_from_cmd_line = metafunc.config.getoption("port")
    print('command line passed for --server ({})'.format(server_from_cmd_line))
    print('command line passed for --port ({})'.format(port_from_cmd_line))
    # check if this function is in a test-class that needs the cmd-line args
    if server_from_cmd_line and port_from_cmd_line and hasattr(metafunc.cls, 'real_server'):
        # now set the cmd-line args to the test class
        metafunc.cls.real_server = server_from_cmd_line[0]
        metafunc.cls.real_port = int(port_from_cmd_line[0])


class TestServerCode(object):
    ''' test-class that might benefit from optional cmd-line args '''
    real_server=None
    real_port = None

    def test_valid_string(self):
        assert self.real_server!=None
        assert self.real_port!=None

    def test_other(self):
        from mypackage import my_server_code
        if self.real_server !=  None:
            assert "couldn\'t find host" not in my_server_code.version(self.real_server, self.real_port)
```

- then run (with HTML coverage, for example) with:

  - `pytest tests\test_junk.py --server="abc" --port=123 --cov-report html --cov=mypackage`

Comment: Good tip, thanks. I used this method to allow passing in a username/password on the command line when running tests. Previously, I had to hardcode credentials in source code, which I really hate.

One negative side-effect is that the username/password is printed to terminal when executing the tests. I don't like this, but it's acceptable considering the console already has the credentials visible when executing Pytest with the additional options (username, password).

Comment: Add a dummy account? Then passwords appearing wont be much of an issue

Answer (score 2):

It seems [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#std-fixture-monkeypatch) also works.

Example:

```py
import sys

def test_example(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(sys, 'argv', ['/path/to/binary', 'opt1', '...'])
    assert f() == '...'

def test_another():
    # sys.argv is not modified here
    assert f() != '...'
```