# Pytest assert if sys. argv == something it will run a function

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to test the main function that if len (sys. argv) < 1 or len (sys. argv) < 4 it will run a function using pytest

this is my main fucntion

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print(print_help())
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2 or len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] == 'help' or sys.argv[1] == 'h' or sys.argv[1] == 'H':
            print(print_help())
    else:
        print('no such command arguments try python project.py help')

def print_help:
    the_help = 'the help section'
    return the_help

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

How can I use pytest to test this main function if sys. argv < 1 that it will run the `print_help` function

or if sys.argv == 'help' or sys.argv == 'h' or sys.argv == 'H' it will run the same fucntion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set sys.argv so I can unit test it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668947/how-do-i-set-sys-argv-so-i-can-unit-test-it)

Comment: in this question they use unittest, I hope that there is an answer using pytest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to handle sys.argv in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110064/how-to-handle-sys-argv-in-pytest)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, but if read the answer on that question it does not answer my question at all I want to assert that when I run `py project. py help` it sure run the help function and nothing else but in this question you sherd its another thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred approach is make your `main()` function take its inputs from a variable instead of from `sys.argv` directly:

```
def main(args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        print(print_help())
    elif len(args) == 2 or len(args) == 3:
        if args[1] == 'help' or args[1] == 'h' or args[1] == 'H':
            print(print_help())
    else:
        print('no such command arguments try python project.py help')

def print_help:
    the_help = 'the help section'
    return the_help

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Now you can use [capsys](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) in your test function to test the output, and can easily pass in whatever list of arguments you want to test without having to patch or mock anything.

Also, [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) does this sort of command line processing for you. I highly, *highly* recommend using it (or other similar libraries) instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: thank you, your approach is better that mine, and for the argparse I use al mot one command that's why I didn't use it my full code is here [link](https://github.com/zakari1231/final_project_cs50p/blob/main/project.py), Again, thank you for this useful approach

Answer (score 1):

I find some kind of answer that helps a little bit
I find it on this  [Github link](https://github.com/source-foundry/font-line/blob/a87018ac825185c1911039619c17e593552181aa/tests/test_main.py)

```
def test_main(capsys):

    from project import main
    sys.argv = ['h', 'H', 'help']
    main()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out.startswith("the help section") is True
```

it check if the output of the `print_help` is the same as entering one of the commands in `sys.argv=  ['h', 'H', 'help']`