# I got an IndexError: list index out of range in sys.argv[1]

Tags: python, index-error

I want to plot this code but it entered

> IndexError: list index out of range in the line: k =
>   float(sys.argv[1])

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

```
canWidth=500
canHeight=500
**strong text**
def setupWindow () :
    global win, canvas
    from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame
    win = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(win, height=canHeight, width=canWidth)
    f = Frame (win)    
    canvas.pack()
    f.pack()

def startApp () :
    global win, canvas
    import sys
    k1  = float(sys.argv[1])   # starting value of K
    k2  = float(sys.argv[2])   # ending   value of K
    x = .2                     # is somewhat arbitrary
    vrng = range(200)          # We'll do 200 horz steps
    for t in range(canWidth) :
        win.update()
        k = k1 + (k2-k1)*t/canWidth
        print ("K = %.04f" % k)
        for i in vrng :
            p = x*canHeight
            canvas.create_line(t,p,t,p+1)  # just makes a pixel dot
            x = x * (1-x) * k              # next x value
            if x <=0 or x >= 1.0 :
                print ("overflow at k", k)
                return

def main () :
    setupWindow()       # Create Canvas with Frame
    startApp()          # Start up the display  
    win.mainloop()      # Just wait for user to close graph

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

Comment: how did you launch the program?

Comment: Did you run your script with at least two command line arguments? e.g. `python3 script.py arg1 arg2`

Comment: If you launch it with `python filename.py`, you get the error. If you launch it with `python filename.py 1 2` for example you don't get an error. I hope it is clear why.

Comment: Do you understand what the [error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) means?

Comment: Do you understand what `argc` and `argv` are?

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the program is expecting 2 float command line arguments.
`

```
k1  = float(sys.argv[1])   # starting value of K
k2  = float(sys.argv[2])
```

`

So you shuld probably launch it with something like

```
python main.py 100 200
```

To go more into detail, your code is reading [command line arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) and it's expecting there to be 2 of them, that can also be parsed into float values.
Normally, the first command line argument is the script file itself, so `sys.argv` is always at least one element long.

That being said, you can either do as suggested above, and pass 2 floats as arguments, when launching the script, or just edit the script and hardcode 2 values instead of the ones read from the command line, like so

```
k1  = 100  
k2  = 200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful. Then, I just pressed F5 every time I want to run the code. Now I know  how to use sys,argv.