# IndexError: list index out of range when trying to program an argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, argv, index-error

I keep getting `IndexError: list index out of range` when using the below snippets in a python script:

```
rhost = sys.argv[1] #target ip
rport = int(sys.argv[2]) #target port
```

I do not really see the issue with the above code.  Any assistance would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like sys.argv does not have 2 or more entries. If you call your script with commandline arguments the list has more than one entry. Do you do that? See this post for a very detailed description on how it works: [sys.argv[1] meaning in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script)

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I need to add a logic check in the script so that if there is not the appropriate amount of arguments it displays an error referencing the usage portion.