# Python executable running files with associated extension

Tags: python, executable, file-handling, cx-freeze, file-association

I have compiled my python program with `cx_Freeze` with the lines

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

to get the name of the extension file that runs my application.
I want to be able to double click on a file named `Foo.bas` and then my compiled executable starts and it can open the file and read its contents. So I want to get the extension path and file name and read its contents like this

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
# do things with contents
```

where file would be the extension path and name

So how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` gives you the first entry of the command used to run your script, which is the script name itself. If you double-click on a file whose extension is associated with your script or frozen application, the name of this file becomes the second argument of the command, which is available through `sys.argv[1]`. See for example [sys.argv[1] meaning in script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4117530/8516269).

So try with the following script:

```py
import os
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print('Trying with', filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
            # do things with contents
else:
    print('No arguments provided.')
input('Press Enter to end')
```

This works both as unfrozen script and as executable frozen with `cx_Freeze`. On Windows you can drag and drop your `Foo.bas` file onto the icon of your script or executable, or right-click on `Foo.bas`, chose `Open with` and select your script or executable as application.

Comment: I only figured that out byt playing around with the command and recieving the file name and Foo.bas file name. I was going to try it until i checked the post again. Thanks