# How can I run a python code with input on Linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, function, jobs

I have a file named `myadd.py` that contains only the following function:

```
def myadd(a,b):
    return a+b
```

How can I run it on Linux terminal?
I am looking for something easy like this:

```
python myadd 2,3
```

My final goal is to send multiple jobs to the server by making a `.sh` file containing:

```
bsub -J job1 python myadd 2,3
bsub -J job1 python myadd 4,5
bsub -J job1 python myadd 6,3
.
.
.
.
```

Let me know if I need to make any changes to be able to do something like the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use command line arguments.

For example, in the following code:

```
import sys

print ('# Args:', len(sys.argv))
print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

If you call it from the terminal...

```
python3 test_args.py ar1 ar2 ar3 ar4 ar5
```

Gives as a result:

```
# Args:: 6
Argument List: ['test_args.py', 'ar1', 'ar2', 'ar3', 'ar4', 'ar5']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `argparse`

code:

```py
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-n", "--numbers", required=True, default=None, type=str,
    help="Input your numbers to add separated by comma")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

numbers = args["numbers"].split(",") # Parse the arguments
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers] # convert from str to int list

def addition(a: int, b: int):
    """Add function"""
    return a+b

print("Result: {}".format(addition(numbers[0], numbers[1])))
```

Usage:

```py
(pyenv)  ✘ rjosyula  ~  python x.py --help
usage: x.py [-h] -n NUMBERS

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n NUMBERS, --numbers NUMBERS
                        Input your numbers to add separated by comma
```

Results in

```py
python x.py --numbers 2,3
Result: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sys.argv` to accept command line arguments. I suggesting using a space between the two numbers instead of a comma. For more details, see [sys.argv[1] meaning in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script) and the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv). If you need more complex command line arguments, I suggest you check out the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) library.

Answer (score 2):

Also the [fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) module.

This only needs:

```
import fire

def myadd(a, b):
    return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(myadd)
```

The import guard was edited in. It isn't needed here as the script is unlikely to be used as a module. I intentional left it out due to that.

To result in a command

```
python script.py 1 2
```

That prints `3`