# What makes argv in python useful?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, parameter-passing, argv

I recently came across this `argv` thing in python. What I've understood is that it is used for passing parameters using command line. Now, my questions are----

1. Is `argv` command-line only? I mean can it be used for command-line programs only?
2. If not, how do I use that in a program? Please share some example code.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sys.argv\[1\] meaning in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script)

Comment: If you used `subprocess.run(["foo.py", "bar", "baz"])`, inside `foo.py` you would see that list as the value of `sys.argv`. No shell is involved; the shell is just one way to provide arguments to a script.