# How to specify where to look for files and path for log files?

Tags: python, working-directory

I have a python script that could up end up in different directories on different servers. My script has sys.path.insert line where it look's for libraries and also looks for config.ini file in the same directory as the script. I want to be able to run the script with the full path.

`example.py`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import sys, getopt, configparser
sys.path.insert(0, '../lib/')
from myFunctions import mySendmail, remoteFileChkSum, sendfile
...
def main():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    # username and encrupted passwords are in config.ini
    # keys for encryption are in .keys
    config.read('config.ini')
    config.read('.keys')
```

On some hosts the file is in `/export/apps/bin/` with the `lib` folder in `/export/apps/lib`. On other hosts it's in `/export/home/ray/bin` with the `lib` folder in `/export/home/ray/lib`.

What is the best practice so I can run the script from anywhere on any host?? Should I find the directory/location of the script at the beginning and perform a `os.chdir('<DIR>')`?

Comment: You could get the current working directory as follows `cwd = os.getcwd()` @Ravi

Comment: @Vishnudev that gives me the current working directory. But I need dir where the script is located since the references to lib and config file are in reference to that

Comment: The best current practice is to make your module installable, and have `pip` install its data files to a system-dependent location which can be retrieved from the package's metadata. For a quick and dirty solution, looks like you can use `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent() / 'lib' / 'config.ini'`

Comment: If you start the program from the commandline and if you use `sys.argv` the the first argument will be the path where the program is running, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script)

Comment: You can get the directory of the currently running script with `os.dirname(__file__)` — which is a very common way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works.

```
import os, sys
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(script_dir)

sys.path.insert(0, '../lib/')
from myFunctions import mySendmail, remoteFileChkSum, sendfile
```