# groking command line parameters in a python script

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I am relatively new to python. I want to write a script and pass it parameters like this:

```
myscript.py --arg1=hello --arg2=world
```

In the script, I want to access the arguments arg1 and arg2. Can anyone explains how to access command line parameters in this way?

Comment: see answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) is part of the standard library (as of versions 2.7 and 3.2). This is the module I use to handle all my command line parsing although there is also [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) (which is now deprecated) and [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html).

The following is a simple example of how to use argparse:

```
import sys, argparse

def main(argv=None):

    if argv is None:
        argv=sys.argv[1:]

    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example of using argparse")

    p.add_argument('--arg1', action='store', default='hello', help="first word")
    p.add_argument('--arg2', action='store', default='world', help="second word")

    # Parse command line arguments
    args = p.parse_args(argv)

    print args.arg1, args.arg2

    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

**Edit**: Note that the use of the leading '--' in the calls to `add_arguments` make `arg1` and `arg2` optional arguments, so I have supplied default values. If you want to program to require two arguments, remove these two leading hypens and they will become required arguments and you won't need the `default=...` option. (Strictly speaking, you also don't need the `action='store'` option, since `store` is the default action).

Comment: your getopt link is broken.  i tried to edit but the change was only 1 character :)

Comment: why do you use `sys.exit(...)` instead of just `main(sys.argv[1:])`?

Comment: @mattwilkie Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit). Basically doing this allows me to pass a return status back to the shell, which typically indicates whether or not the script was run succesfully. Also, calling `sys.exit` causes some clean up actions to be performed, such as any `finally` clauses on `try` statements.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

simple example can help

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module included with the standard library.  It makes this stuff a breeze once you get used to it, and it is very robust. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/index.html).  It is recommended to use this rather than the optparse or getopt modules.

If you don't want use the module but still want to access the arguments, check out the [sys module](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).  You will want to look at sys.argv.

Comment: +1 For the link to the Doug Hellmann tutorial - it is a very useful introduction to argparse.

Answer (score 1):

Python supplies 3 different ways of parsing command line arguments, not including any you write yourself using raw access to the parameter list.

http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-389-the-argparse-module-for-parsing-command-lines

> The argparse module for parsing command-line arguments was added as a
>   more powerful replacement for the optparse module.
>
> This means Python now supports three different modules for parsing
>   command-line arguments: getopt, optparse, and argparse. The getopt
>   module closely resembles the C library’s getopt() function, so it
>   remains useful if you’re writing a Python prototype that will
>   eventually be rewritten in C. optparse becomes redundant, but there
>   are no plans to remove it because there are many scripts still using
>   it, and there’s no automated way to update these scripts. (Making the
>   argparse API consistent with optparse‘s interface was discussed but
>   rejected as too messy and difficult.)
>
> In short, if you’re writing a new script and don’t need to worry about
>   compatibility with earlier versions of Python, use argparse instead of
>   optparse.