# how to execute a python script file with an argument?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command Line Arguments In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Example:

```
itp.threads[0].memload(r"c:\FistForSOCAD_PASS.bin","0x108000P")
itp.threads[0].cv.cip = "0x108000"
itp.go()
itp.halt()
```

I would like to make above example as a python script and "FistForSOCAD_PASS.bin" can be replaced by an argument. Because it is only the variable thing.

Example command to run the script will be like:

`python itp.py FistForSOCAD_PASS.bin`

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of ways, One is this approach:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

Which gives:

```
$ prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]

Process some integers.

positional arguments:
 N           an integer for the accumulator

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --sum       sum the integers (default: find the max)
```

Read more at [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

Answer (score 4):

You may use [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html):

> **sys.argv**
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). [...]

Example:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module.