# Put an argument into a string

Tags: python, string, variables, arguments, sys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command Line Arguments In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

I am using Python 3.2. What I would like to do is basically a program that exports text into a .txt file, like this:

```
[program name] "Hello World" /home/marcappuccino/Documents/Hello.txt
```

I am a newbie and I dont know how to take whtever's in between the two ""s and place that into a variable. Is it in `sys.argv`?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: "Hello World" is the string i would like to save, and /home/marca.../Hello.txt is the directory I would like to save it in BTW

Comment: I am not trying to create a help argument or anything to do with optparse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html), which holds the command line arguments. You would want something like:

```
string_to_insert = sys.argv[1]
file_to_put_string_in = sys.argv[2]
```

This would assign "Hello World" to `string_to_insert` and /home/marcappuccino/Documents/Hello.txt to `file_to_put_string_in`.

Let's say you have a script named "dostuff.py" and you invoke it like this:

```
dostuff.py "Hello World 1" "Hello World 2" hello world three
```

What you will end up with is:

```
sys.argv[0] = dostuff.py (might be a full path, depending on the OS)
sys.argv[1] = Hello World 1
sys.argv[2] = Hello World 2 
sys.argv[3] = hello 
sys.argv[4] = world 
sys.argv[5] = three
```

Arguments in quotes are considered a single argument.

Comment: so [1] and [2] are words seperated by spaces? if so then what if the usr put a string like this "Hello world" as opposed to "helloworld"?

Comment: Crummy formatting; see edited answer.

Comment: But i dont understand what the []s do,. How do they discern from [1] and [2] 3 etc? - how are they seperated?

Comment: If you don't understand what [] does, I would suggest you start from the very basics and do some reading about arrays/lists.

Comment: I understand, and i am in fact  learning by creating this program. anyway i dont think your update came to me by the time i posted that comment. so i just want to understand when the []s end, for example, they might stop whenever there is a space or a symbol.

Comment: eg `program hello world lol` would be `sys.argv[1] == "hello"` `sys.argv[2] == "world"` and `sys.argv[3] == "lol"`..?

Comment: So, how does your example work then? sureley sys.argv[1] would be "Hello, and sys.argv[2] would be World, and sys.argv[3] would be 1"?

Comment: The arguments are split by spaces.  The first element of sys.argv is always the filename (i.e. sys.argv[0]) and the second one is sys.argv[1]

Comment: the args are split by spaces, yes, but how are the [ ]s split?

Comment: It appears that slicing in python is that [1] selects the first character of the word and [2] selects the second etc, [1:2] selects everything in betwenn 1st and 2nd characters, but i cannot find out how to take anything between a character like "

Comment: so how do i do something like `usrtext = sys.argv["*"]` (the asterisk being an autocomplete for whatever is whitin two quotation marks)?

Comment: You don't. sys.argv is a list. List items are accessed via their index; i.e., sys.argv[0] is the first item in the list, sys.argv[1] is the second item in the list, etc.

See: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down a simple program to demonstrate what I believe you need.  You have to add escape characters in the input to take the quotes as is.

```
import sys

for i in range(0, len(sys.argv)):
    print sys.argv[i]
```

Output:

```
python testing.py a b c "abcd"
testing.py
a
b
c
abcd

python testing.py a b c \"abcd\"
testing.py
a
b
c
"abcd"
```

Comment: thanks but, i just realised that argv was a list, and i now realise that answer 1 answered my question! if i could upvote i would but i am 1 rep...