# Getting paths as user input Python 3

Tags: python

I want the user to be able to type paths as arguments for my program
The progeram should work over all OS...
Until now i used x=input("...") and parsed this x as my path
But in Unix it is more complicated, in case i run my program from ~/a/c/b and i want the argument to be directory 'a', i should type ../../ ?
What should i write in Unix in order to get correct path... ?
Or is there another module to use in order to get user paths in the template above ?

Thank you !

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: i'm asking how to get these paths as full paths... should i use input() ? raw_input() is there better modules for input paths handling ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert relative paths to absolute paths? You can use [`os.path.abspath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath).

Comment: in python 2, "input" will treat `4/2` as 2. You should never use input in python 2. Why do you need to do any handling at all? You're trying to solve a problem that you've never had.

Comment: I think the absolute path is the answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use relative paths such as `../../` because you may never know from where the user runs your application. If your program is in `~/a/c/b` and you want the argument to be directory `a`, then you should just use `~/a` as the argument.

As for writing the same code to run on all operating systems, you should use things such as `os.path.join` and `os.path.normpath`. More info on how to handle paths in python [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

Comment: When i type any '/' in Unix i get SyntaxError, it doesn't happen in Windows, only in Unix, it happens when i use input(), when i use raw_input() it doesn't happen in Unix but i get an error in Windows

Comment: Why are you talking about `input` and `raw_input`? If you want to use command line arguments, you don`t have to use any of those two functions. Read this SO question to see how to use command line arguments in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python

Comment: When the user doesn't provide arguments or invalid arguments i would like the user to type the arguments into CMD, that's why i need input()/raw_input()