# Reading command Line Args

Tags: python

I am running a script in python like this from the prompt:

```
python gp.py /home/cdn/test.in..........
```

Inside the script i need to take the path of the input file `test.in` and the script should read and print from the file content. This is the code which was working fine. But the file path is hard coded in script. Now I want to call the path as a command line argument.

## Working Script

```
             #!/usr/bin/python
             import sys
             inputfile='home/cdn/test.in'
             f = open (inputfile,"r")
             data = f.read()
             print data
              f.close()
```

## Script Not Working

```
              #!/usr/bin/python
              import sys
              print "\n".join(sys.argv[1:])
              data = argv[1:].read()
              print data
              f.close()
```

What change do I need to make in this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python check this related question.

Comment: in your non working script, what does this do `argv[1:].read()`? argv is a list of string, right? I think it has to be `data = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read()`.

Answer (score 3):

While Brandon's answer is a useful solution, the reason your code is not working also deserves explanation.

In short, a list of strings is not a file object. In your first script, you `open` a file and operate on that object (which is a file object.). But writing `['foo','bar'].read()` does not make any kind of sense -- lists aren't `read()`able, nor are strings -- `'foo'.read()` is clearly nonsense. It would be similar to just writing `inputfile.read()` in your first script.

To make things explicit, here is an example of getting all of the content from all of the files specified on the commandline. This does not use `fileinput`, so you can see exactly what actually happens.

```
# iterate over the filenames passed on the commandline
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    # open the file, assigning the file-object to the variable 'f'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # print the content of this file.
        print f.read()

# Done.
```

Comment: Nice answer, I bow to your calmness. I'm trying hard to be calm at explaining things that are **soo** clear to me but not others.. +1

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `fileinput` module: it interprets command line arguments as filenames and hands you the resulting data in a single step!

http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html

For example:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

Comment: Thx Brandon,OnesimusUnbound and Kampu.  it worked...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the script that isn't working for you, you are simply not opening the file before reading it. So change it to

```
          #!/usr/bin/python

          import sys

          print "\n".join(sys.argv[1:])
          f = open(argv[1:], "r")
          data = f.read()

          print data
          f.close()
```

Also, `f.close()` this would error out because `f` has not been defined. The above changes take care of it though.

BTW, you should use at least 3 chars long variable names according to the coding standards.