# How do I accept user input on command line for python script instead of prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have python code which asks user input. (e.g. src = input('Enter Path to src: ').          So when I  run code through command prompt (e.g. python test.py) prompt appears 'Enter path to src:'. But I want to type everything in one line (e.g. python test.py c:\users\desktop\test.py). What changes should I make? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `src = input('Enter Path to src: ')` with:

```
import sys
src = sys.argv[1]
```

Ref: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

If your needs are more complex than you admit, you could use an argument-parsing library like [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) (deprecated since 2.7), [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) (new in 2.7 and 3.2) or [getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html).

Ref: [Command Line Arguments In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

---

Here is an example of using argparse with required source and destination parameters:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import argparse
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Copy a file")
parser.add_argument('src', metavar="SOURCE", help="Source filename")
parser.add_argument('dst', metavar="DESTINATION", help="Destination filename")
args = parser.parse_args()

shutil.copyfile(args.src, args.dst)
```

Run this program with `-h` to see the help message.

Comment: +1 for completeness, in mentioning getopt, which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @Rob so I have src = sys.argv[1] and dst = sys.argv[2] How can I put this in argparse or optparse?

Answer (score 5):

[argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) or [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) are your friends. Sample for optparse:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
              help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
              action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
              help="don't print status messages to stdout")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

and for argparse:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
               help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
               const=sum, default=max,
               help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: so I have src = sys.argv[1] and dst = sys.argv[2] How can I put this in argparse or optparse?

Comment: @user2661518 You put them in as options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.argv[1]` to get the first command line argument.  If you want more arguments, you can reference them with `sys.argv[2]`, etc.