# Passing arguments from sh script(remade from etc/init.d/skeleton) to python

Tags: python, unix, daemon, init.d, daemons

I have a script and I need him to pass arguments to python program. I take arguments:

```
DAEMON_ARGS=""
start-stop-daemon --start --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON    \
   $DAEMON_ARGS \                                                  
   || return 2
```

Where $DAEMON is path to my .py file. I need to pass some numeric arguments like this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sleepdaemon start 10
```

And this number I must pass to sleep.py. The code of sleep.py:

```
#! env/bin python

import time
sleep(n)
```

How do I make n = 10(the argument that wass pass from console) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the arguments to your daemon invocation:

```
DAEMON_ARGS="start 10"
```

Second, consume them in your python program:

```
#! env/bin python

import sys
n = sys.argv[2]

import time
sleep(n)
```

Look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) for more detailed information about command line arguments use in Python.

Comment: Thanks. It should be n=sys.argv[2] so n=10

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.argv`

```
import time
import sys

time.sleep(int(sys.argv[11])
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python) for a related discussion