# How do I provide an input file in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

How would I pass in an input file to a Python script from the command line, like this:

`python mycode.py inputFile inputParameter`

Comment: Initially I couldn't understand what this was asking so I raised a flag, but after rereading it several times, I think I was able to find out what the person was asking. I heavily edited what was here to reflect what I think their real question was. I suspect this should be closed as a duplicate, perhaps of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read it in python:

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
```

Comment: @Dave - This certainly isn't a new question. It may be a request for clarification from the author like Simone suggested. The question isn't even remotely clear though.

Comment: My mistake i flagged incorrectly when i was going through the flag system. Thanks for alerting me :) @ArtOfWarfare