# Python command line argument assign to a variable

Tags: python, logic, command-line-arguments

I have to either store the command line argument in a variable or assign a default value to it.

What i am trying is the below

```
import sys
Var=sys.argv[1] or "somevalue"
```

I am getting the error **out of index** if i don't specify any argument. How to solve this?

Comment: Maybe use a more structured approach, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @Barmar: In principle yes, but that's overkill for this scenario, don't you think?

Comment: Perhaps. We don't see the full context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Var=sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "somevalue"
```

Comment: Nice one-liner, I only began using this 'perl-like' method a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 5):

The builtin [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) module is intended for exactly these sorts of tasks:

```
import argparse

# Set up argument parser
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Single positional argument, nargs makes it optional
ap.add_argument("thingy", nargs='?', default="blah")

# Do parsing
a = ap.parse_args()

# Use argument
print a.thingy
```

Or, if you are stuck with Python 2.6 or earlier, and don't wish to add a requirement on the [backported argparse module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse), you can do similar things manually like so:

```
import optparse

opter = optparse.OptionParser()
# opter.add_option("-v", "--verbose") etc
opts, args = opter.parse_args()

if len(args) == 0:
    var = "somevalue"
elif len(args) == 1:
    var = args[0]
else:
    opter.error("Only one argument expected, got %d" % len(args))

print var
```

Comment: why not directly `opter.add_option('--var', default="somevalue")`? See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

I think the best solution would be to do

```
try:
    var = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    var = "somevalue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with a command-line-processing template:

```
def process_command_line(argv):
    ...
    # add your option here
    parser.add_option('--var',
        default="somevalue",
        help="your help text")

def main(argv=None):
    settings, args = process_command_line(argv)
    ...
    print settings, args # <- print your settings and args
```

Running `./your_script.py` with the template below and your modifications above prints `{'var': 'somevalue'} []`

For an example of a command-line-processing template see an example in *Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python* (http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#command-line-processing):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Module docstring.
"""

import sys
import optparse

def process_command_line(argv):
    """
    Return a 2-tuple: (settings object, args list).
    `argv` is a list of arguments, or `None` for ``sys.argv[1:]``.
    """
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv[1:]

    # initialize the parser object:
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(
        formatter=optparse.TitledHelpFormatter(width=78),
        add_help_option=None)

    # define options here:
    parser.add_option(      # customized description; put --help last
        '-h', '--help', action='help',
        help='Show this help message and exit.')

    settings, args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    # check number of arguments, verify values, etc.:
    if args:
        parser.error('program takes no command-line arguments; '
                     '"%s" ignored.' % (args,))

    # further process settings & args if necessary

    return settings, args

def main(argv=None):
    settings, args = process_command_line(argv)
    # application code here, like:
    # run(settings, args)
    return 0        # success

if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = main()
    sys.exit(status)
```