# python how to read data after script name

Tags: python

I am new to python and would like to give the arguments to a script as in-line arguments after the script name.

For example: given the script

```
mypython_script.py
```

I would like to launch it from terminal in the following way:

```
python3.4 mypython_script.py argument_1=5.0, argument_2=12.3, nome_file='out_put.dat'
```

I am able to read/print into terminal via the following command:

```
print ('Input Argument_1')
string_input= input()
Argument_1=float(string_input)
print('Argument_1 %f ' % Argument_1)

print ('Input Argument_2')
string_input= input()
Argument_2=float(string_input)
print('Argument_2 %f ' % Argument_2)

print ('Input nome_file')
nome_file= input()
print('nome_file %s ' % nomefile)
```

But in order to do this I have to interact with the program, my question is: how can I give to the script all the arguments in the line in which I execute it from shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to retrive parameter after scripts

`sys.argv[0]` will give you first argument.

Please use different argument as `python script_name.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`

If you have to use unix type argument syntext like `python script arg1=val1 arg2=val2` then user [`argparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`argparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) for information on how to use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module. It's an easy-to-use yet powerful module for interacting with command-line arguments, setting up help messages, formatting printouts, and more.