# How to get parameter from command line in python

Tags: python

Now I want to run my program "python a.py x y".

Here x and y are my paraters, so how could I get the input into the program?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: a little research before asking, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys


def some_function_in_your_code(x):
    print("the filename of this program is:", x)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv # this object will have all of your arguments in it
    print sys.argv[0] # this is alwys the name/path? of the python file
    some_function_in_your_code(sys.argv[0])
```

so using your example, if you passed in "x y" into your program, sys.argv would be a list 3 items long like this: `['the/path/to/the/program/a.py', 'x', 'y']`

Comment: If you need more functionality, checkout the argparse library.

Answer (score 1):

you need to look on [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):

> sys.argv
>
> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.
>
> To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the command line, see the fileinput module.