# Placing a Python variable inline

Tags: python, kodi

Forgive this rather basic Python question, but I literally have very little Python experience. I'm create a basic Python script for use with Kodi:

http://kodi.wiki/view/List_of_built-in_functions

Example code:

```
import kodi

variable = "The value to use in PlayMedia"

kodi.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(variable)")
kodi.executebuiltin("PlayerControl(RepeatAll)")
```

Rather than directly providing a string value for the function PlayMedia, I want to pass a variable as the value instead. The idea is another process may modify the variable value with sed so it can't be static.

Really simple, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So you want to call a function, but you only have the name of the function as string?

Comment: The PlayMedia function accepts a string value, I want to have a variable as the value which is set to something already.

Comment: At a guess I thought this would work? kodi.executebuiltin("PlayMedia("playlistpath")")

Comment: My attempts thus far has been either syntax errors or the variable being interpreted as a literal string and not the variable value.

Comment: Try searching Python command line parameters...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple case of [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

```
template = "{}({})"
functionName = "function"  # e.g. input from user
arg = "arg"  # e.g. input from user
formatted = template.format(functionName, arg)
assert formatted == "function(arg)"
kodi.executebuiltin(formatted)
```

Comment: This seems to be what I am after. Apologies if my original question was vague.

Comment: Once again, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is your friend for the future.

Answer (score 0):

OK as far as I get your problem you need to define a variable whose value could be changed later, so the first part is easier, defining a variable in python is as simple as `new_song = "tiffny_avlord_I_love_u"`, similarly you can define another string as  `new_video = "Bohemia_on_my_feet"`, the thing to keep in mind is that while defining variables as strings, you need to encapsulate all the string inside the double quotes `"..."` (However, single quotes also work fine)

Now the issue is how to update it's value , the easiest way is to take input from the user itself which can be done using `raw_input()` as :

```
new_song = raw_input("Please enter name of a valid song: ")
print "The new song is : "+new_song
```

Now whatever the user enters on the console would be stored in the variable `new_song` and you could use this variable and pass it to any function as

```
some_function(new_song)
```

Try executing this line and you will understand how it works.

Comment: Understood. In this case, I would need to place the value of new_song inline, within the kodi.executebuiltin function. What's the best way to do it?