# How to make a function accept runtime arguments

Tags: python

I want to define a function such that I want it to accept command line arguments

below is my code

```
def tc1(resloc):
    from uiautomator import Device;
    'Do some activity'
    with open(resloc, 'a') as text_file:
            text_file.write('TC1 PASSED \n')
            text_file.close()
    else:
        with open(resloc, 'a') as text_file:
            text_file.write('TC1 FAILED \n')
            text_file.close()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc1("C:\\<pathtoautomation>\\Results\results.txt")
```

Now when I execute the same using command line from python it continues to refer to the path mentioned here  `tc1("C:\\<pathtoautomation>\\Results\results.txt")` and doesn't consider what I pass in the runtime from the command line

```
\Scripts>python.exe trail.py C:\\<pathtoautomationresults>\\Results\results.txt
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: You want `tc1(sys.argv[1])` or possibly a loop over `sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0]
>   is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a
>   full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c
>   command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string
>   '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0]
>   is the empty string.
>
> To loop over the standard input, or the list of files given on the
>   command line, see the fileinput module.

You use it like:

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    # do something with argv.


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])  # the argv[0] is the current filename.
```

and call it using

`python yourfile.py yourargsgohere`

Check out a more detailed use [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to get command line parameters.

in your code it could look like this:

```
import sys
...  # other stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc1(sys.argv[1])
```

There are many [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) out there that help you use `sys.argv`