# What is an elegant way to call one of several (possibly static) member functions by sending arguments to a Python script?

Tags: python

The following code in file `script.py` makes it possible (after `chmod 755 script.py`) to either `script.py dothis` or to `script.py dothat`.

```
import sys

class DoThisOrThat:
    @staticmethod
    def dothis():
        print "We're doing this."

    @staticmethod
    def dothat():
        print "We're doing that."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Error: You must specify exactly one function: dothis or dothat"
        sys.exit(1)
    if sys.argv[1] == "dothis":
        FooBar.dothis()
    elif sys.argv[1] == "dothat":
        FooBar.dothat()
    else:
        print "I don't know how to "+sys.argv[1]
```

Is this the most elegant way to call one of two static member methods from the command line?

Solutions using either `argparse` or `argh` are [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33660737/704972) if the methods are nonmember. What is the equivalent for the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` builtin to call any methods (static / instance / class) of a class (or of an instance)

Assuming your `Factory` class is

```
>>> class DoThisOrThat:
    @staticmethod
    def dothis_static():
        print "We're doing this static."

    @staticmethod
    def dothat():
        print "We're doing that static."
    def dothis_instance(self):
        print "We're doing this instance."
    @classmethod
    def dothis_classmethod(cls):
        print "We're doing this class method."
```

Then a possible invocation would be

```
>>> getattr(DoThisOrThat, 'dothis')()
We're doing this.
>>> getattr(DoThisOrThat(), 'dothis_instance')()
We're doing this instance.
>>> getattr(DoThisOrThat, 'dothis_classmethod')()
We're doing this class method.
```

This modifies your code as

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Error: You must specify exactly one function: dothis or dothat"
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        getattr(DoThisOrThat, sys.argv[1])()
    except AttributeError:
        print "I don't know how to " + sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow calling arbitrary staticmethods of a class from the commandline, you can also use `getattr` to accomplish this, assuming of course the argument and method names match 1-to-1:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Error: You must specify exactly one function")
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        getattr(DoThisOrThat, sys.argv[1])()
    except AttributeError:
        print("Error: The specified method '%s' does not exist" % sys.argv[1])
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary to map the strings to the functions.

```
>>> d = {'dothis': DoThisOrThat.dothis, 'dothat': DoThisOrThat.dothat}
>>> d['dothis']()
We're doing this.
>>> d['dothat']()
We're doing that.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Error: You must specify exactly one function: dothis or dothat"
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        d[sys.argv[1]]()
    except KeyError:
        print "I don't know how to "+sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Might it be possible to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33660814/704972 by writing f = MyObject...[args.thing]? What would the "..." be?