# Passing currenttime as parameter into Python command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, arguments, python-unittest

I run my Python scripts with `python -m unittest discover` command. I'd like to passing current time `yyyymmddhhmmss`as parameter into execution command.

How can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: actually, my question is to produce a runtime cuurrendate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sample the current time on the system running the puthon code, you can use `datetime.datetime.now()` (local time) or `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` (UTC).

Then you can format as string using `.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`.

Comment: can i use it as a parameter?

Comment: To which function do you want to pass the parameter?

Comment: .strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") that you presented

Comment: That's just the conversion from a `datetime` object into a string with yyyymmddHHMMSS format. But where does the date/time sting go? Which function needs the infomation?

Comment: i think i couldn't clear the question: i have multiple python files. i run with command that i presented in question. i need that because, i will use same parameter for several purposes in each class(as an id)