# command line parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, command-line

well I'm brand new to Python and I'm really struggling to solve the following puzzle. Namely, I'm writing a script that's supposed to take and process arguments from the command line in the following different cases:

--X x1 x2 x3

--X range xmin xmax

First command should do all the calculations in points x1, x2, x3.
And when a user issues the second command it should do the same calculations in [Xmin, Xmax]. And "range" is a control word here implying that the calculations will be done in range. X is parameter's name.

Namely, when I issue the first command, my script should calculate 
I don't really know how to go about it, everything I tried didn't work the way I want it to...

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What have you **tried already**?  There's plenty of information on command line parameters out there..  Why is your scenario different?

Comment: Do some research - start with `argparse`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: I tried doing it with the help of subparsers but to no avail. I reckon, it must be done throgh some hand-made action, but I didn't really understand the example in tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example, showing how to obtain the command line arguments.  The code is simple; I named my file **so.py**

```
import sys
print "arguments:", sys.argv
```

Now, when you execute with command-line arguments, **sys.argv** is a list of all the arguments:

```
$ python2.7 so.py --X 5 7 9
arguments: ['so.py', '--X', '5', '7', '9']
```

You can manipulate this just as any other list -- but I strongly recommend that you not alter the list.  Access the elements as needed, copy it to another list, etc. -- but do not change the original.

Comment: I do know how to work with the parser. But what I want is nothing like what you wrote.
As you can see, I've got two optional arguments, one of them is --X and the second one is "range" which is actually a command name. 
So in the first case everything is easy:
parser.add_argument('--x', ......,nargs= '*'), that would allow a user to enter any number of points "x", but what if he wanted to make calculations in the range , say, from Xmin to Xmax.

Comment: You haven't yet posted your non-working code, as required by the StackOverflow guidelines.  Where are you stuck?  Clarify your question.  Briefly, you check the first argument after **--X**: if it's "range", then you loop from Xmin through Xmax; otherwise, you iterate through the given list of values.