# I am trying to process a file passed as a command line argument

Tags: python

I am trying to process a file passed as a command line argument.  Right now there is only one argument, but I plan to add others.

Here is my code so far:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Sample arg parsing")

parser.add_argument('-f',type=file)

try:
    print parser.parse_args()
except IOError, msg:
    parser.error(str(msg))
```

I can't figure out how to pass the argument to file handle to open and process.
And yes, I am a n00b.
The try block is just there for testing.

Comment: arguments are text - it can't be file - but you can use [FileType objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) to convert filename to file.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  The seems to say that by using FileType it is opening the file implicitly for me.  So I am still stuck with how do I reference it so that I can process it?

Comment: `args = parser.parse_args()` and then `args.f` because you used name `-f`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the filename as a string. Then, you can use open() to open the file from the filename. Refer to the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) (7.2 - Reading & Writing Files).

Comment: OK...that makes sense.  But how do I reference the passed argument to set it equal to a string?

Comment: It will already be a string, you just have to read its value. The first example here shows you how to read an argument value: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#introducing-positional-arguments

Comment: Ah!  So whatever is in the first position of the add_argument method becomes the argument's name that can then be referenced, right?

Comment: Thanks Patrick and furas ~ between the two of you I got there!