# append the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one csv file like this

```
out.csv
seedProductId,relatedProducts
```

My output is in dftype object looks like this

```
100A7E54111FB143    
100D11CF822BBBDB    
1014120EE9CCB1E0    
10276825CD5B4A26    
10364F56076B46B7    
103D1DDAD3064A66    
103F4F66EEB54308
```

I want to append this output with delimiter '|'.And I will pass another input as dynamic.

so I want the op like this

```
out.csv
seedProductId, relatedProducts
103F4F66EEB54308, 100A7E54111FB143 | 100D11CF822BBBDB | 10276825CD5B4A26 ...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why `seedProductId` is `103F4F66EEB54308`? Because last item in output?

Comment: no I just mentioned for example purpose.I will pass the seedproduct id at run time

Comment: So you need only convert your output from many rows to one row separated by `|`?

Comment: yes.and then I want to append into my csv file

Comment: `out.csv` is new file or contains data before appending?

Comment: it contains data .that is column name

Comment: yes..can u help me how to write the object into file with delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) for merging data, then create new `Series` for each columns and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them. Last write output dataframe to `file` by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
print df
                  A
0  100A7E54111FB143
1  100D11CF822BBBDB
2  1014120EE9CCB1E0
3  10276825CD5B4A26
4  10364F56076B46B7
5  103D1DDAD3064A66
6  103F4F66EEB54308

seedProductId = "id790"
s1 = pd.Series(seedProductId, name='seedProductId')
print s1
0    id790
Name: seedProductId, dtype: object

relatedProducts = df.A.str.cat(sep='|')
print relatedProducts
100A7E54111FB143|100D11CF822BBBDB|1014120EE9CCB1E0|10276825CD5B4A26|10364F56076B46B7|103D1DDAD3064A66|103F4F66EEB54308

s2 = pd.Series(relatedProducts, name='relatedProducts')
print s2
0    100A7E54111FB143|100D11CF822BBBDB|1014120EE9CC...
Name: relatedProducts, dtype: object

df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

print df.to_csv(index=False)
seedProductId,relatedProducts
id790,100A7E54111FB143|100D11CF822BBBDB|1014120EE9CCB1E0|10276825CD5B4A26|10364F56076B46B7|103D1DDAD3064A66|103F4F66EEB54308
```

Comment: Ok, I think `dftype object` is for me dataframe with column `A`. But what is your `dtfype object`? Dataframe? Series? Something else?

Comment: Yes, you can change it to `relatedProducts = output['ProductId'].str.cat(sep='|')`

Comment: Hi nice.it works for me..I am now trying to append the output in my csv file

Comment: the last line is not working for me..any help ?  print df.to_csv(index=False)

Comment: I think you need add filename `df.to_csv("filename.csv", index=False)`

Comment: last doubt is it possible to pass arguments to my program..                                   rating_toby = rp['1021C789EC57BBC1']  I need to pass like this                                                                                         rating_toby = rp['param']

Comment: Maybe you can create variable `param` - `param='1021C789EC57BBC1'` and then use it: `rating_toby = rp[param]`

Comment: no not like this .I am going to execute like this python filename.py (here i need to define the argument)

Comment: `rp` is function? is defining like `def rp()` ?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you think [command line arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)?

Comment: I think it is for new question. Sorry, I dont know help you. But maybe help this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)