# How to add a custom flag to IPython's magic commands? (.ipy files)

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

Is it possible to add a custom flag to IPython's magic command? To be more specific, I want to use the %run command with a homemade flag:

```
%run script.ipy --flag "option"
```

and be able to use "option" inside the script.

For .py files, the answer is provided here: [Command Line Arguments In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: Have you tried this? What didn't work?

Comment: The syntax works, but I don't know how to access the flag in the script.

Comment: Either use one of the approaches (e.g. `argparse`) provided in that linked question, or just use `import sys; sys.argv` directly (it's a list)

Comment: It works very well, thank you. Do you know how to do it for a .ipy file? sys.argv gives me ['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\ipython'] when I run a .ipy file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, this question isn't just about handling commandline arguments in a Python script.  It's about handling them in an `.ipy` file run via `%run`.

If I create `test.ipy` as

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

and run it from shell, I see the commandline arguments:

```
1223:~/mypy$ python3 test.ipy -test foo
['test.ipy', '-test', 'foo']
```

but from a `ipython` session, I don't

```
In [464]: %run test.ipy --flag test
['/usr/bin/ipython3']
```

If I make a copy with a `py` name

```
In [468]: %run testipy.py --flag test
['testipy.py', '--flag', 'test']
```

So the `%run ...ipy` behaves differently.  This is a `ipython` issue, not a general Python commandline one.

================

The `%run` doc has this point:

> There is one special usage for which the text above doesn't apply:
>   if the filename ends with .ipy[nb], the file is run as ipython script,
>   just as if the commands were written on IPython prompt.

In that case, the `test.ipy` script is seeing the same `sys.argv` as I do when I type:

```
In [475]: sys.argv
Out[475]: ['/usr/bin/ipython3']
```

So if I modify `sys.argv` in the current session, such as by appending a couple of strings:

```
In [476]: sys.argv += ['--flag','test']

In [477]: sys.argv
Out[477]: ['/usr/bin/ipython3', '--flag', 'test']

In [479]: %run test.ipy
['/usr/bin/ipython3', '--flag', 'test']
```

my `ipy` script now sees them.

So that's the answer - put the commandline arguments in the `sys.argv` prior to using `%run ...ipy`.

(I've done this sort of fiddling with the `sys.argv` when doing advanced things with `argparse`.)

More `ipython` magic

```
In [480]: %run??
```

shows me both its doc and its code.  I can thus see how it is treating a `.ipy` file special.  Since it's so easy to find, I'll refrain from copying it here.

There's another solution - don't try to use the commandline style of coding with `ipy` files.

If I add a

```
print(x)
```

line to that test file, and have an `x` defined in my Ipython session, I see that print.  But I put that same print in a `.py`, I'll get a `Nameerror`.  When they say the `ipy` is run as though it were typed in, they mean it.  Running an `ipy` is, in effect, an alternative to `%paste` from the clipboard.

Comment: Interesting and helpful in many cases, but in mine it won't do. "test" has to be any string (it acts as a way for the user to add a comment). Also I need to use .ipy files because I'm calling magic commands.

Comment: You may have to give a more concrete example.  What's the relationship between the `main` namespace, and the `ipy's`?  Maybe `%run` isn't the right tool.

Comment: What kinds of magics are you using?  Something like `%hist` that accesses the current namespace?  Or `%ls` which can be run in standalong `ipython` session?

Comment: I suppose I could redesign my scripts into .py files, and run them interactively with the -i flag. However, I can't find a way to do a clean Ipython reset like the one provided by %reset.