# IPython run magic: How create an alias for "run -i"?

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

I am programming a python user interface to control various instruments in a lab. If a script is not run interactively, the connection with instruments is lost at the end of the script, which can be very bad. I want to help the user to 'remember' running the script interactively.

I'm thinking of two possible ways to do it. First, as specified in the title, I could make an alias for `run -i`:

```
%alias_magic lab_run run -i
```

but this returns an error:

```
UsageError: unrecognized arguments: -i
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Alternatively, I could detect inside the script if the `-i` flag was passed on and raise en error if not. However, it doesn't show up in the `sys.argv` list:

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: run -i test.py random args
['test.py', 'random', 'args']
```

I can't use ipy files, because I need to read %run flags, as explained in my previous question here:
[How to add a custom flag to IPython's magic commands? (.ipy files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210320/how-to-add-a-custom-flag-to-ipythons-magic-commands-ipy-files/38211195)

Anyone sees a solution to this problem?

Comment: `-i` is parsed by `%run`, and isn't in the extras that it passes to your script as `sys.argv`.

Comment: Looks like `%alias_magic` doesn't take arguments, just the 2 strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your own magic function and use `%run -i` in it:

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

@register_line_magic
def r(line):
    get_ipython().magic('run -i ' + line)

del r
```

**EDIT**

As hpaulj points out `magic` is deprecated. Here a version with the new
`run_line_magic`:

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

@register_line_magic
def r(line):
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', ' -i ' + line)

del r
Now:

%r
```

does the same as:

```
%run -i
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)

Comment: According to its docs, this 'magic' is deprecated.  It recommends `ip.run_line_magic(magic_name, line)` instead.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the pointer.  But is still used internally `%pwd`, `_ih[-2]`,
`"get_ipython().magic('pwd')"`.

Comment: In the latest implementation `ip.magic` uses `ip.run_line_magic`, after splitting name from line.  But it's certainly possible that haven't rewritten all older uses.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Mike for [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277783/15446311), it pointed me in the right direction for making a *cell* magic alias

I found that `%alias_magic [-l] [-c] [-p PARAMS] name target`, in the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), does the trick for me

in my case:

```
%alias_magic --cell py_310 script -p C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python
```

output

```
Created `%%py_310` as an alias for `%%script C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python`.
```

that can then be used like

```
%%py_310

import sys

print(sys.version_info)
```

output

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```