# Starting a Python script from bash with a string placed into stdin

Tags: python, bash, stdin

How do I start a Python script with some input already waiting in stdin.  For example, say I have this simple script located in `main.py`, using Python3:

```
mystr = input()
print(mystr)
```

If you just called `python3 main.py` from the terminal, the script would pause and wait for you to type something.  After hitting enter it would continue and print out what you typed.  But is there a way to place something into stdin before the script executes?  That way the script wouldn't pause, it would accept what's already there.  I was envisioning something like:
`python3 main.py | my string` but that doesn't work.

**Note that I am not asking about command line arguments:**  I am writing an application which will have to take input from stdin, so I am looking for a convenient solution to test out that environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Comment: Does `echo 'my string' | python3 main.py` not work?

Comment: Or if you have have a file of sample input, `cat my_input | python3 main.py`.

Comment: @Jonathan your solution works.  If you turn it into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't depend on the fact that a Python script is involved, and the same methods work for feeding bytes into the stdin of any process started under bash (you might want to add a `bash` tag to your question to reflect this):

To feed a short string into it

```
echo 'my string' | python3 main.py
```

To feed a file of sample input into it

```
cat my_input | python3 main.py
```

You can also feed a file like this

```
python3 mail.py < my_input
```

[Note: Some people like to spend a lot of time arguing that method 3 is better than method 2, (search for 'useless use of cat' if you're interested), but I've come to prefer method 2 (for reasons that are beyond the scope of your question). Use whichever makes the most sense to you.]

Comment: Cool, I added the `bash` tag