# Passing SSH password input via python

Tags: python

I have written a simple code wherein I invoked ssh to one of my lab Device ip through `os.system`.  Now the problem for me is how do I supply a password? Can I do it via python?

Below is the code that I have been using:

```
import os
os.system("ssh 192.168.1.100")
```

I tried to understand how the `os` module works but so far am not able to supply password argument - how do I supply a password via python to this program?

My environment is Bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Install sshpass, then launch the command with os.system like that:

```
os.system("sshpass -p \'yourpassword\' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no yourusername@hostname")
```

Or you can use a fabric script to copy your public key into the system then you will not need a password for connection

```
from fabric.api import env, sudo, run
def copy_pub_key(ip, user, password, pub_key):

    env.host_string = ip
    env.user = user
    env.password = password

    if user == "root":
        sudo('echo \'{pub_key}\' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys'.format(
            pub_key=pub_key,
            user=user
        ))
    else:
        sudo('echo \'{pub_key}\' >> /home/{user}/.ssh/authorized_keys'.format(
            pub_key=pub_key,
            user=user
        ))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. ultimate goal is to automate a login and in a kind of official environment i cannot add any packages apart from what system give me so.

Comment: Then you should use fabric script to copy the public key into the system then you can connect without password.