# How to take input in beginning of the program in python?

Tags: python, shell

NOTE: I have posted a very similar question by myself but please note before duplicating this question that the language is different this is a python and that is a shell script.
I am making a program in python which needs the user input in the beginning of the program if you don't get my question I will give you an example:

I am making a program which needs the user input in the beginning of the program if you don't get my question I will give you an example:

```
./script.py "some-input"
```

So, I want the input in the beginning of the program. I think the input will be stored in a variable. If yes, Then please tell me in which variable it is stored. I am a Python rookie please never hesitate to correct the question. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access that variable via:

```
import sys
sys.argv[1]
```

more details and examples can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

Comment: Thank you, Ohad Eytan! This worked for me!! I will make this as my answer soon.