# How do I read a command line argument from Python?

Tags: python

I am new to python programming, but basically I want to have a script where when given a file path from the command line (the file being a .csv file), the script will take this file and turn it into a list.

Code I have seen for this problem usually doesn't take the file from the command line, rather it just has the exact filename in the code. I want to use this code on many different files, so hard coding the file name into the program is not an option.

Comment: This question should have everything you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python. For a very simple script you can see the sys.argv related answer, then level up to argparse which will be useful in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change you need to make to the code that you've already found is this:

```
import sys
filepath = sys.argv[1]
... # process file
```

And now, you invoke your script like this: `./script.py /path/to/file`.

[`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is used to read command line arguments. Optional commands start from index `1`, because `argv[0]` stores the name of your script (`script.py`).