# Running a python.py file with datas

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code allows you to resize and view the file named "lena-gray.png" in the same folder.

```
from PIL import Image

jpgfile = Image.open("lena-gray.png")

high = input("Genişliğini giriniz : ")
wid = input("Yüksekliğini giriniz : ");

out = jpgfile.resize((int(high), int(wid)))

out.show()
```

But instead of entering these values step by step, I want to enter

```
$ python mywork.py lena-gray.png 50 100
```

So I want to run it without opening the file and see the result. Can this be done on Phyton? Can you help me?

> ----------------------------------------Edit----------------------------------

```
I updated my code like down. 

import sys
from PIL import Image

firstarg = str(sys.argv[1])
secondarg = int(sys.argv[2])
thirdarg = int(sys.argv[3])

jpgfile = Image.open(firstarg)

yuks = secondarg

gen = thirdarg

out = jpgfile.resize((int(yuks), int(gen)))

out.show()
```

[image]

And my codes work!

[image]

Comment: You may want to update the question. The problem has nothing to do with image processing or algorithms...

Comment: Well, the tags were only an example. The title is also completely off. You are asking about command line arguments in Python. What are "datas" supposed to be?

Comment: I solved! I will edit my answer. That doesn't hardly.

Comment: The problem with your question is that because tags and title were/are completely off, it's not obvious that this is a duplicate of many older questions (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments). If you/I/someone fixes that, it needed to be flagged as such right away. At first I thought pointers to the docs should be enough, since it seems you simple didn't know the terminology to ask the correct question. If you had known it, a Google search ("python command line arguments") would have been enough.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

It's the standard Python way to handle command line arguments.

EDIT: And if you want to check if the file is actually there or allow giving a list of files, look into [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

EDIT2: This should do:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("filename", help="an image file", type=str)
parser.add_argument("width", help="display width", type=int)
parser.add_argument("height", help="display height", type=int)
clargs = parser.parse_args()


from PIL import Image

jpgfile = Image.open(clargs.filename)
out = jpgfile.resize(clargs.height, clargs.width)
out.show()
```

EDIT3: If you really want to do it according to the answer by @tendstoZero, this should be correct:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
height = int(sys.argv[2])
width = int(sys.argv[3])


from PIL import Image

jpgfile = Image.open(filename)
out = jpgfile.resize(height, width)
out.show()
```

You shouldn't cast to `int` twice, and you shouldn't use meaningless intermediate variables.

Comment: I solve with Image and sys and I use sys.argv[]. thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well, I already tried to explain why you should not use `sys.argv` ... For one final reason, try `python script.py -h` on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
firstarg=sys.argv[1]
secondarg=sys.argv[2]
thirdarg=sys.argv[3]
sys.argv[0] should be the script name .
```

You should be using something like this above snippet in your script.

Comment: Sure. That's possible too. But it has no built-in checks if the arguments are valid, etc. So, argparse is certainly the better choice.

Comment: I want to find that answer, but my problem is so critical. So I must to find my answer quickly. Do you want to help edit my codes?

Comment: I added a full solution to my answer. I'm still sure you want to read the docs about the two modules I mentioned.