# Unable to pass the argument value from the conole

Tags: python

Iam trying with a simple script where i wanted to print the value that parsed via command line. But while running the script, it doesn't produce the expected output

the program name is python commadn_line_argu.py

```
import sys


def main():
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print "Given arfument is ", arg

if __name__=="_main_":
   main()
```

please see the attached screen shot for the same
[image]

Appreciate if anyone can help on it

Thanks

Comment: You didn't give it any command line argument to pass in. Command line arguments are given as so: `python commadn_line_argu.py first_argument second_argument third_argument`

Comment: You were not giving any arguments on the commandline :-)

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as a simple typographical error. Reason being, others who search for a question like "Unable to pass the argument value from the console" probably are not experiencing this same error, as leaving out the arguments you are supposed to be passing is a misunderstanding of what command line arguments are rather than an actual issue with the code to pass in those values, so this question is unlikely to help others searching for an issue with this title.

Answer (score 1):

give it as python filname.py argument_name

Answer (score 1):

First, when executed as a script, the module's magic variable `__name__` is set to `"__main__"` (not `"_main_"` - notice the *double* underscores), so you have to fix this test.

Then of course, if you don't pass any argument on the command line, you can't expect to have any output here...

Answer (score -1):

The `__name__` value when a module is run directly is `__main__`, not `_main_`. Change the value you check against and you should be good to go. (Remember to actually pass in some arguments though!)

Comment: No function is "called when a module is run directly", unless you _explicitely_ call one, and then the name of this function is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Typo. Should have said "value" not "function".

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)
You can find more details there, or use the following code:

```
import sys

def main():
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print "Given argument is ", arg

#_main_ should be __main__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```