# Pass CMD Arguments to python

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-arguments

basic scenario:

building an interpreter for some basic scripting language, I need to specify the file to run, so that I could, in CMD type `$ customlang /path/to/file/file.lang`

I've looked into argparse, but what i've seen is that it parses arguments in the form of `--argument` which isn't quite what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: Thanks. do I need to import it?

Comment: Argparse can not only parse flags but also positional arguments as you would like. There are many argument parsing libraries (argparse, docopt, click, invoke, optik,...) and all should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of task I would use [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) because of its simplicity and readability.

Here's an example that fits your needs for the argument "name":

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='number of greetings')
@click.argument('name')
def hello(count, name):
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)
```

Please note the difference here between option and argument.

A simpler example, using standard libraries, would be:

```
import sys

print "1st argument is " + sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: My pleasure, @JacobSchneider!
Please remember to upvote and/or choose the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I haven't forgotten, but every time I try it tells me I can accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: I haven't forgotten, but every time I try it tells me I can accept the answer in 10 minutes. But it works now