# Pass command line argument to python script

Tags: python, command, arguments

I have a file.py that I want to pass `base_url` to when called, so that `base_url` variable value can be dynamic upon running `python file.py base_url='http://google.com'`  the value of `http://google.com` could then be used directly in the execution of file.py.

How might I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line arguments are stored in the list `sys.argv`. `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the command that was invoked.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.stderr.write("usage: {} base_url".format(sys.argv[0]))
    exit(-1) # or deal with this case in another way
base_url_arg = sys.argv[1]
```

Depending on the input format, `base_url_arg` might have to be further processed.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv`.

[How to use `sys.argv` in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)

For parsing arguments passed as `"name=value"` strings, you can do something like:

```
import sys

args = {}
for pair in sys.argv[1:]:
    args.__setitem__(*((pair.split('=', 1) + [''])[:2]))

# access args['base_url'] here
```

and if you want more elaborate parsing of command line options, use `argparse`.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)'s a tutorial on `argparse`.