# Passing arguments to python script via terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-2.7, shell-exec

I have this python script, I now open an image from a given path in the script itself, what I need is a dynamical way to pass the image to the script.

For example: `python pixel.py 9tiff`, I will be running this from php with shell exec and I will need to pass different images each time, so I can't hard code the image name in to a script itself

```
import os, sys
import Image

im = Image.open('/www/test/tiffFiles/9.tiff')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
r0, g0, b0 = rgb_im.getpixel((20, 20))
r1, g1, b1 = rgb_im.getpixel((40, 40))
r2, g2, b2 = rgb_im.getpixel((60, 60))
print(r0, g0, b0)
print(r1, g1, b1)
print(r2, g2, b2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: `Sys.argv`. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing command line arguments in python are fairly simple. you can change the your script to as follows:

```
import sys
import Image

if __name__ =='__main__':
    im = Image.open(str(sys.argv[1]))
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    r0, g0, b0 = rgb_im.getpixel((20, 20))
    r1, g1, b1 = rgb_im.getpixel((40, 40))
    r2, g2, b2 = rgb_im.getpixel((60, 60))
    print(r0, g0, b0)
    print(r1, g1, b1)
    print(r2, g2, b2)
```

In Python argv[0] variable is always reserved for the name of the python script. `python myScript.py 9tiff` here `argv[0]` is held by **myScript.py** and `argv[1]` is used by **9tiff**

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of similar questions out there, but if you want an easy solution, use [`sys.argv`](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv)

```
import sys
print "This is the name of the script: ", sys.argv[0]
print "Number of arguments: ", len(sys.argv)
print "The arguments are: " , str(sys.argv)
```

But the best is always [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```