# How could I get the command line that I entered in the terminal to run a python file?

Tags: python, command-line

Suppose I have a python file main.py, and it has some optional parameters, --learning-rate, --batch-size, and etc.

If I want to run this file, I can input the following into the terminal(Ubuntu Linux for example).

`python3 main.py --learning-rate 0.1 --batch-size 100`

And now, I want to write some code in main.py, in order that after I enter the command above, I can get this command in a string by executing those code. The following is the string I want to get:

"python3 main.py --learning-rate 0.1 --batch-size 100"

The reason I want to do this is that I want to write this string into my recording file so that I can know better what command I have run.

Could anyone tell me what package should I import and what code should I write to get that command information during running the python file?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: `sys.argv` contains the arguments; the exact string that produces those arguments isn't readily available to Python, as the shell may have processed it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot always get precisely what you typed, because the shell will have first done substitutions and expanded filenames before starting your script. For example, if you type `python "foo.py" *.txt`, your script won't see `*.txt`, it will see the list of files, and it won't see the quotes around `foo.py`.

With that caveat out of the way, the `sys` module has a variable named `argv` that contains all of the arguments. `argv[0]` is the name of the script.

To get the name of the python executable you can use `sys.executable`.

To tie it all together, you can do something like this:

```
print(sys.executable + " " + " ".join(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remake the command using the arguments you parsed? It won't be exactly what you typed, but that might be nice as it will be in a common format.

Ex (assuming the learning rate and batch size are stored in similarly named variables):

```
command = "python3 main.py --learning-rate {} --batch-size {}".format(learning_rate, batch_size)
```

Of course it will be a little more complicated if some commands are optional, but I assume in that case there would be a default value for these parameters, since your network would need those parameters every time.

Comment: Thank you! I guess in some cases I have some optional parameters, so use `sys` can be more helpful